# Select longest continuous sequence

Tags: postgresql, gaps-and-islands, window-functions, postgresql-9.0

I am trying to construct a query in PostgreSQL 9.0 that gets the longest sequence of continuous rows for a specific column.

Consider the following table:

```
lap_id (serial), lap_no (int), car_type (enum), race_id (int FK)
```

Where `lap_no` is unique for each `(race_id, car_type)`.

I would like the query to produce the longest sequence for a given `race_id` and `car_type`, so it would return an `int` (or long) that is highest.

With the following data:

```
1, 1, red, 1
2, 2, red, 1
3, 3, red, 1
4, 4, red, 1
5, 1, blue, 1
6, 5, red, 1
7, 2, blue, 1
8, 1, green, 1
```

For `car_type = red and race_id = 1` the query would return `5` as the longest sequence of the `lap_no` field.

I found a similar question [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17045/efficiently-select-beginning-and-end-of-multiple-contiguous-ranges-in-postgresql) however my situation is a bit more straightforward.

<sub>(I would also like to know the longest sequence for a given `car_type` for all races, but was planning to work that out myself.)</sub>

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your description results in a **table definition** like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
   lap_id   serial PRIMARY KEY
 , lap_no   int NOT NULL
 , car_type enum NOT NULL
 , race_id  int NOT NULL  -- REFERENCES ...
 , UNIQUE(race_id, car_type, lap_no)
);
```

#### General solution for this class of problems

To get the longest sequence (1 result, longest of all, arbitrary pick if there are ties):

```
SELECT race_id, car_type, count(*) AS seq_len
FROM  (
   SELECT *, count(*) FILTER (WHERE step)
                      OVER (ORDER BY race_id, car_type, lap_no) AS grp
   FROM  (
      SELECT *, (lag(lap_no) OVER (PARTITION BY race_id, car_type ORDER BY lap_no) + 1)
                 IS DISTINCT FROM lap_no AS step
      FROM   tbl
      ) x
   ) y
GROUP  BY race_id, car_type, grp
ORDER  BY seq_len DESC
LIMIT  1;
```

`count(*) FILTER (WHERE step)` only counts `TRUE` (= step to next group), which results in a new number for every new group.

Related **procedural solution with plpgsql**:

- [GROUP BY and aggregate sequential numeric values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8014694/939860)

If the top requirement is performance, the *plpgsql function is typically faster* in this particular case because it can calculate the result in a single scan.

#### Faster for consecutive numbers

We can capitalize on the fact that ***consecutive*** `lap_no` define a sequence, for a **much simpler and faster version**:

```
SELECT race_id, car_type, count(*) AS seq_len
FROM  (
   SELECT race_id, car_type
        , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY race_id, car_type ORDER BY lap_no) - lap_no AS grp
   FROM   tbl
   ) x
GROUP  BY race_id, car_type, grp
ORDER  BY seq_len DESC
LIMIT  1;
```

Consecutive laps end up in the same `grp`. Every missing lap results in a lower `grp` per partition.

This relies on `(race_id, car_type, lap_no)` being `UNIQUE NOT NULL`. NULL values or duplicates could break the logic.

#### Discussion of Jack's simpler alternative

[@Jack's version](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/35398/3684) effectively counts all laps (rows) where the previous `lap_no` in this `race_id` had the same `car_type`. That's simpler and faster and correct - as long as each `car_type` can only have *one* sequence per `race_id`.

**But** for a task that simple the query could be simpler, yet. It would follow logically that all `lap_no` per `(car_type, race_id)` must be *in sequence*, and we could just count the laps:

```
SELECT race_id, car_type, count(*) AS seq_len
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY race_id, car_type
ORDER  BY seq_len DESC
LIMIT  1;
```

If, on the other hand, one `car_type` can have *multiple separate sequences* per *race_id* (and the question does not specify otherwise), Jack's version will fail.

#### Faster for a given race / car type

In reply to the comment / clarifications in the question: restricting the query to **one given** `(race_id, car_type)` will make it *much faster*, of course:

```
SELECT count(*) AS seq_len
FROM  (
   SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY lap_no) - lap_no AS grp
   FROM   tbl
   WHERE  race_id = 1
   AND    car_type = 'red'
   ) x
GROUP  BY grp
ORDER  BY seq_len DESC
LIMIT  1;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=e4738848f19ac7734526597757bbdf81)*
<sub>Old [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/3824a/1)</sub>

### Index

Key to top performance is a fitting index (except for the mentioned procedural solution working with a single sequential scan). A [multicolumn index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-multicolumn.html) like this serves best:

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_mult_idx ON tbl (race_id, car_type, lap_no);
```

If your table has the `UNIQUE` constraint I assumed at the top, that is implemented with just this (unique) index internally, and you do *not* need to create another index.

Comment: Hi Erwin, thanks that does the job, however it takes ~17sec on my database! Dont suppose you could provide a modification so it takes race_id and car_type as parameters rather than comparing the entire table? (I have tried re-writing it and keep running into errors)

Answer (score 7):

> ```
> create table tbl (lap_no int, car_type text, race_id int);
> ```
>
> ```sql
> insert into tbl values (1,'red',1),(2,'red',1),(3,'red',1),(4,'red',1),
>                        (1,'blue',1),(5,'red',1),(2,'blue',1),(1,'green',1);
> ```
>
> ```sql
> select car_type, race_id, sum(case when lap_no=(prev+1) then 1 else 0 end)+1 seq_len
> from ( select *, lag(lap_no) over (partition by car_type, race_id order by lap_no) prev 
>        from tbl ) z
> group by car_type, race_id
> order by seq_len desc limit 1;
> ```
>
> ```sql
> /*
> |car_type|race_id|seq_len|
> |:-------|------:|------:|
> |red     |      1|      5|
> */
> ```

Comment: or perhaps `sum((lap_no=(prev+1))::integer)+1` but I'm not sure that is easier to read