# Group by maximum consecutive row

Tags: mysql, postgresql, group-by, gaps-and-islands

I have data like the following:

```
id  | src_ip         | dst_ip       | port |
----|----------------|--------------|------|
256 | 192.168.61.200 | 10.75.64.222 | 80   |
257 | 192.168.61.200 | 10.75.64.222 | 81   |
258 | 10.65.72.207   | 10.75.64.223 | 80   |
259 | 10.75.254.27   | 10.75.64.223 | 82   |
260 | 10.75.254.27   | 10.75.64.224 | 80   |
261 | 10.75.254.27   | 10.75.64.230 | 80   |
262 | 10.75.254.27   | 10.75.64.230 | 81   |
263 | 10.75.254.27   | 10.75.64.230 | 82   |
264 | 10.75.254.27   | 10.75.64.230 | 83   |
265 | 10.75.254.27   | 10.75.64.230 | 84   |
```

I built the schema and loaded the same data here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1185c

I'm planning to group the rows in a way to reproduce some rules for my firewall. Given the firewall supports ranges for ports or IPs I want to query this table and group as many rows as I can to produce valid rules.

There are a few different ways to group rows, but I want to start grouping by consecutive `dst_ip` on the same port.

Given the table presented above, I would like to get something like this:

```
 dst_ip       | max_consecutive | port |
--------------|-----------------|------|
 10.75.64.222 | 10.75.64.224    | 80   |
 10.75.64.222 | 10.75.64.222    | 81   |
 10.75.64.223 | 10.75.64.223    | 82   |
 10.75.64.230 | 10.75.64.230    | 80   |
 10.75.64.230 | 10.75.64.230    | 81   |
 10.75.64.230 | 10.75.64.230    | 82   |
 10.75.64.230 | 10.75.64.230    | 83   |
 10.75.64.230 | 10.75.64.230    | 84   |
```

Note: `max_consecutive` could be the number of consecutive rows, too, not necessarily the upper IP.

Actually, if I can go deeper, I would like to group by `port`, too. That means the last 5 rows of the result will be summarized in just one like

```
 10.75.64.230 | 10.75.64.230    | 80   | 84
```

I'm currently using MySQL, but I can move to PostgreSQL if it is necessary.

Comment: This looks like a classic group by to me, but I do not quite get what results you expect. Can you be more specific and add the expected full result for your example ?

Comment: Would you continue a series across byte boundaries? I.e. is the series `10.75.63.254, 10.75.63.255` continued with `10.75.64.0`?

Comment: No, I don't care that scenario right now. Because it will depend on the mask too, so I prefer to ignore it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **Postgres** (tested with v9.3) you can use the dedicated [**`inet`** data type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-net-types.html#DATATYPE-INET-VS-CIDR), to store IPv4 addresses with only 7 bytes (or IPv6 with 19 bytes) and with automatic integrity checks and [dedicated functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-net.html) and type casts etc.

#### Schema

The translated schema could look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE log (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY
, dst_port int
, src_ip inet
, dst_ip inet
);
CREATE INDEX ON log (dst_port);
CREATE INDEX ON log (src_ip);
```

I moved to `dst_port int` to the 2nd position to optimize alignment / padding:

- [Configuring PostgreSQL for read performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42290/configuring-postgresql-for-read-performance/43142#43142)

Now we can use standard [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html) (not possible in MySQL).

#### Step 1: Fold groups of consecutive `dst_ip` for same (`dst_port`)

One *special difficulty*: The aggregate function `min()` / `max()` are not yet implemented for `inet` in Postgres 9.4. [Both are in the upcoming Postgres 9.5!](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CAG1_KcBcavTb2OUoGi1PrAVRs_x4r9afmBK9P0djJnB_3afy8w@mail.gmail.com#CAG1_KcBcavTb2OUoGi1PrAVRs_x4r9afmBK9P0djJnB_3afy8w@mail.gmail.com)

So I substituted with `DISTINCT ON` in the first step:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (dst_port, ip_grp)
       dst_ip, count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY dst_port, ip_grp) AS ip_ct, dst_port
FROM  (
   SELECT dst_ip, dst_port, dst_ip - row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY dst_port
                                                        ORDER BY dst_ip) AS ip_grp
   FROM   log
   ORDER  BY dst_port, dst_ip
   ) sub
ORDER  BY dst_port, ip_grp, dst_ip;
```

Result as desired - with a count of rows (could be upper IP as well).

You can subtract/add `integer` from/to the `inet` type. By subtracting the `row_number()` all consecutive rows get the same `grp` - the value of `grp` is irrelevant, just the fast that it's the same per partition (`dst_port`).

Then we can `GROUP BY ...` - or in this special case `DISTINCT ON dst_port, ip_grp`. I use another window function to get the count `ip_ct` in the same step: `count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY dst_port, ip_grp) AS ip_ct`.

Note that consecutive IPs can cross byte boundaries (see my comment to question).

Detailed explanation for this technique:

- [Select longest continuous sequence](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35380/select-longest-continuous-sequence/35389#35389)

#### Step 2: Fold groups of consecutive `dst_port` for same `(dst_ip, ip_ct)`

```
SELECT dst_ip, ip_ct, min(dst_port) AS dst_port, count(*) AS port_ct
FROM  (
   SELECT *, dst_port - row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY dst_ip, ip_ct
                                           ORDER BY dst_port) AS port_grp
   FROM  (
      SELECT DISTINCT ON (dst_port, ip_grp)
             dst_ip, count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY dst_port, ip_grp) AS ip_ct, dst_port
      FROM  (
         SELECT dst_ip, dst_port, dst_ip - row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY dst_port
                                                              ORDER BY dst_ip) AS ip_grp
         FROM   log
         ORDER  BY dst_port, dst_ip
         ) sub1
      ORDER  BY dst_port, ip_grp, dst_ip
      ) sub2
   ) sub3
GROUP  BY 1, 2, port_grp
ORDER  BY 1, 3, 2;
```

Basically, repeat the same logic like in the first step, applied to the result of the first step.
But now you have to group on `ip_ct` additionally. And this time, you can use the simpler `min(dst_port)`, since the port number is a plain `integer`.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/64893/25) demonstrating all.

Comment: This looks really great. The only thing is for port grouping, I would like to have the first row of the second query to be like: `10.75.64.222 | 3 | 80 | 2` where `port_ct` value is 2 given the same ip has 80 and 81

Comment: @emancu: But that would be wrong / ambiguous. `(10.75.64.223, 81)`,  `(10.75.64.223, 81)` and  `(10.75.64.224, 81)`,  `(10.75.64.224, 81)` are missing.

Comment: I'm not following you :(. It shouldn't be ambiguous. Given a `src_ip` we say there are 3 consecutive `src_ip` with the same `port`, and at the same time there are 2 consecutive `ports` with the same `src_ip`

Comment: @emancu: `and at the same time there are 2 consecutive ports with the same src_ip`  .. but only for `src_ip` 10.75.64.222, not for .223 and .224. My last comment was inaccurate, should be: `(10.75.64.223, 81)`, and `(10.75.64.224, 81)` are missing. The row represents an aggregated range of 3 IPs, not just the one.