# Calculate number of consecutive years (not gapless)

Tags: postgresql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have a request that wants to look at numbers of consecutive year buyers. For example, I have a table like this:

```
Order_year, Contact
2015, 123
2014, 123
2013, 123
2011, 123
2010, 123
2015, 234
2014, 234
2011, 234
```

I want to calculate for each year how many consecutive order years each `contact_id` has. The problem is, there are gaps such as `contact_id = 123`, it has 2010-2011, then 2013-2015.

The output would be:

```
report_year, contact, consecutive_years
2015, 123, 3
2014, 123, 2
2013, 123, 1
2012, 123, 0
2011, 123, 2
2010, 123, 1
2015, 234, 3
2014, 234, 2
2013, 234, 1
2012, 234, 0
2011, 234, 1
```

Or if you just want to calculate the max order year with the max consecutive years, that's fine, such as:

```
order_year, contact, consecutive_years
2015, 123, 3
2011, 123, 2
2015, 234, 2
```

Answer (score 3):

So I've built a short SQL script to do this operation, based on the original sample input data:

```
Order_year, Contact
2015, 123
2014, 123
2013, 123
2011, 123
2010, 123
2015, 234
2014, 234
2011, 234
```

The script is as follows:

```
WITH RECURSIVE ranked_order AS(
  SELECT order_year, contact, 1 AS counter FROM orders
  UNION
  SELECT orders.order_year, orders.contact, ranked_order.counter + 1
  FROM orders JOIN ranked_order
  ON orders.order_year-1 = ranked_order.order_year
  WHERE orders.contact = ranked_order.contact
),
max_from_ranked_order AS(
  SELECT order_year AS report_year, contact, max(counter) AS consecutive_year 
  FROM ranked_order
  GROUP BY order_year, contact
),
start_and_consecutive_years AS(
  SELECT  contact, max(consecutive_year) AS consecutive_years, 
  report_year - consecutive_year AS start_year
  FROM max_from_ranked_order
  GROUP BY contact, start_year)
SELECT *, start_year + consecutive_years AS end_year 
FROM start_and_consecutive_years 
ORDER BY contact;
```

Now, for a little explanation:

## Recusive Query

First, you need to find all the occasions of consecutive years, so I built the `ranked_order` table(maybe a bad name... maybe should have called it `counted_order`?) to count instances where a given contact ordered in back-to-back years.

## Filter Results

So, due to the recursive query, I am left with all counted elements, rather than simply the maximum consecutive counts.  So, I built `max_from_ranked_order` to extract the max counter value per `order_year,contact` grouping.

## A little arithmetic...

This still doesn't quite yield what we need.  Since we grouped over `order_year,contact`, you still end up with entries like

```
report_year, contact, consectuive_year
2015, 123, 3
2014, 123, 2
2013, 123, 1
2015, 234, 2
2014, 234, 1
etc...
```

What you'll notice is that you have unique, information which you can group on by observing the starting year of the consecutive years.  So, I created `start_and_consecutive_years` to take the maximum number of consecutive purchasing years for any given starting year, on a per customer basis.

Finally, I get my result by adding the `consecutive_years` to the `start_year`, and presto, the final `SELECT` yields:

```
contact, consecutive_years, start_year, end_year
123, 3, 2012, 2015
123, 2, 2009, 2011
234, 2, 2013, 2015
234, 1, 2010, 2011
```

Note that it would be very easy to filter out for cases`WHERE consecutive years >= 2` to ignore "irrelevant" results.

Now for the caveats: I wrote this series of CTEs for ease of readability and explanation.  There may be a more computationally or programatically efficient way to achieve your results, but on even a moderately sized table this should get you your results pretty quick.

Answer (score 2):

To get all gapless time ranges per contact summed up:

```
SELECT max(order_year) AS order_year, contact, count(*) AS consecutive_years
FROM  (
   SELECT *, order_year - row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY contact
                                             ORDER BY order_year) AS grp
   FROM   orders
   ) sub
GROUP  BY contact, grp
ORDER  BY contact, 1;
```

To get just the longest run per contact, add `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (contact)
       max(order_year) AS order_year, contact, count(*) AS consecutive_years
FROM  (
   SELECT *, order_year - row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY contact
                                             ORDER BY order_year) AS grp
   FROM   orders
   ) sub
GROUP  BY contact, grp
ORDER  BY contact, count(*) DESC;
```

Result:

```
order_year | contact | consecutive_years
-----------+---------+------------------
2015       | 123     | 3
2015       | 234     | 2
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/92d1c/1)

The trick is to - per `contact` - subtract the running count (`row_number()`) from each year. Consecutive rows produce the same group number (`grp`). the number itself has no meaning, it just identifies groups per `contact`.

Then count, sort, get the maximum count. Voilá.

Details for `DISTINCT ON`:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/939860)

Related answer with more explanation for the basic technique:

- [Select longest continuous sequence](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35380/select-longest-continuous-sequence/35389#35389)

Answer (score 0):

My solution with Oracle SQL:

```
with ranked as (
    select c.contact, c.order_year, rank() over (partition by name order by year) rank from contest_prize c
),
ranked_2 as (
select r1.contact, r1.order_year, r1.rank  from ranked r1 inner join ranked r2 on r1.contact= r2.contact
where r2.order_year- r1.order_year= 1 and r2.rank - r1.rank = 1
),
ranked_3 as (
select r1.contact, r1.order_year, r1.rank  from ranked r1 inner join ranked r2 on r1.contact= r2.contact
where r2.order_year- r1.order_year= 2 and r2.rank - r1.rank = 2
)
select r.* from ranked r inner join ranked_3 r3 on r.contact= r3.contact and r.rank between r3.rank and r3.rank + 2;
```