# Form groups of consecutive rows with same value

Tags: postgresql, group-by, window-functions, gaps-and-islands, postgresql-8.4

I have a situation I think can be solved using window function but I'm not sure.

Imagine the following table

```
CREATE TABLE tmp (
  date timestamp
, id_type integer
) ;

INSERT INTO tmp (date, id_type)
VALUES
    ( '2017-01-10 07:19:21.0', 3 ),
    ( '2017-01-10 07:19:22.0', 3 ),
    ( '2017-01-10 07:19:23.1', 3 ),
    ( '2017-01-10 07:19:24.1', 3 ),
    ( '2017-01-10 07:19:25.0', 3 ),
    ( '2017-01-10 07:19:26.0', 5 ),
    ( '2017-01-10 07:19:27.1', 3 ),
    ( '2017-01-10 07:19:28.0', 5 ),
    ( '2017-01-10 07:19:29.0', 5 ),
    ( '2017-01-10 07:19:30.1', 3 ),
    ( '2017-01-10 07:19:31.0', 5 ),
    ( '2017-01-10 07:19:32.0', 3 ),
    ( '2017-01-10 07:19:33.1', 5 ),
    ( '2017-01-10 07:19:35.0', 5 ),
    ( '2017-01-10 07:19:36.1', 5 ),
    ( '2017-01-10 07:19:37.1', 5 );
```

I'd like to have a new group at each change of value in column `id_type`.
E.G. 1st group from 7:19:21 to 7:19:25, 2nd starting and finishing at 7:19:26, and so on.

At this moment, using the query below ...

```
SELECT distinct 
    min(min(date)) over w as begin, 
    max(max(date)) over w as end,   
    id_type
FROM tmp
GROUP BY id_type
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY id_type)
ORDER BY begin;
```

I get the following result:

```
begin                   end                     id_type
2017-01-10 07:19:21.0   2017-01-10 07:19:32.0   3
2017-01-10 07:19:26.0   2017-01-10 07:19:37.1   5
```

While I'd like:

```
begin                   end                     id_type
2017-01-10 07:19:21.0   2017-01-10 07:19:25.0   3
2017-01-10 07:19:26.0   2017-01-10 07:19:26.0   5
2017-01-10 07:19:27.1   2017-01-10 07:19:27.1   3
2017-01-10 07:19:28.0   2017-01-10 07:19:29.0   5
2017-01-10 07:19:30.1   2017-01-10 07:19:30.1   3
2017-01-10 07:19:31.0   2017-01-10 07:19:31.0   5
2017-01-10 07:19:32.0   2017-01-10 07:19:32.0   3
2017-01-10 07:19:33.1   2017-01-10 07:19:37.1   5
```

Once that works, I want to include more criteria to define groups, and these others will be nullable.

Postgres Version: 8.4. We have Postgres with PostGis, so it is not easy to upgrade. PostGis functions change names and there are other problems, but we are already rewriting everything and the new version will use a newer version 9.X with PostGis 2.x.

Comment: General solution: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35380/select-longest-continuous-sequence/35389#35389

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a few points,

- Don't call a non-temporary table `tmp` that just gets confusing.
- Don't use text for timestamps (you're doing that in your example we can tell because the timestamp didn't get truncated and has `.0`)
- Don't call a field that has time in it `date`. If it has date and time, it's a timestamp (and store it as one)

Better to use a window function..

```
SELECT id_type, grp, min(date), max(date)
FROM (
  SELECT date, id_type, count(is_reset) OVER (ORDER BY date) AS grp
  FROM (
    SELECT date, id_type, CASE WHEN lag(id_type) OVER (ORDER BY date) <> id_type THEN 1 END AS is_reset
    FROM tmp
  ) AS t
) AS g
GROUP BY id_type, grp
ORDER BY min(date);
```

Outputs

```
 id_type | grp |          min          |          max          
---------+-----+-----------------------+-----------------------
       3 |   0 | 2017-01-10 07:19:21.0 | 2017-01-10 07:19:25.0
       5 |   1 | 2017-01-10 07:19:26.0 | 2017-01-10 07:19:26.0
       3 |   2 | 2017-01-10 07:19:27.1 | 2017-01-10 07:19:27.1
       5 |   3 | 2017-01-10 07:19:28.0 | 2017-01-10 07:19:29.0
       3 |   4 | 2017-01-10 07:19:30.1 | 2017-01-10 07:19:30.1
       5 |   5 | 2017-01-10 07:19:31.0 | 2017-01-10 07:19:31.0
       3 |   6 | 2017-01-10 07:19:32.0 | 2017-01-10 07:19:32.0
       5 |   7 | 2017-01-10 07:19:33.1 | 2017-01-10 07:19:37.1
(8 rows)
```

### Explaination

First we need resets.. We generate them with `lag()`

```
SELECT date, id_type, CASE WHEN lag(id_type) OVER (ORDER BY date) <> id_type THEN 1 END AS is_reset
FROM tmp
ORDER BY date;

         date          | id_type | is_reset 
-----------------------+---------+----------
 2017-01-10 07:19:21.0 |       3 |         
 2017-01-10 07:19:22.0 |       3 |         
 2017-01-10 07:19:23.1 |       3 |         
 2017-01-10 07:19:24.1 |       3 |         
 2017-01-10 07:19:25.0 |       3 |         
 2017-01-10 07:19:26.0 |       5 |        1
 2017-01-10 07:19:27.1 |       3 |        1
 2017-01-10 07:19:28.0 |       5 |        1
 2017-01-10 07:19:29.0 |       5 |         
 2017-01-10 07:19:30.1 |       3 |        1
 2017-01-10 07:19:31.0 |       5 |        1
 2017-01-10 07:19:32.0 |       3 |        1
 2017-01-10 07:19:33.1 |       5 |        1
 2017-01-10 07:19:35.0 |       5 |         
 2017-01-10 07:19:36.1 |       5 |         
 2017-01-10 07:19:37.1 |       5 |         
(16 rows)
```

Then we count to get groups.

```
SELECT date, id_type, count(is_reset) OVER (ORDER BY date) AS grp
FROM (
  SELECT date, id_type, CASE WHEN lag(id_type) OVER (ORDER BY date) <> id_type THEN 1 END AS is_reset
  FROM tmp
  ORDER BY date
) AS t
ORDER BY date

         date          | id_type | grp 
-----------------------+---------+-----
 2017-01-10 07:19:21.0 |       3 |   0
 2017-01-10 07:19:22.0 |       3 |   0
 2017-01-10 07:19:23.1 |       3 |   0
 2017-01-10 07:19:24.1 |       3 |   0
 2017-01-10 07:19:25.0 |       3 |   0
 2017-01-10 07:19:26.0 |       5 |   1
 2017-01-10 07:19:27.1 |       3 |   2
 2017-01-10 07:19:28.0 |       5 |   3
 2017-01-10 07:19:29.0 |       5 |   3
 2017-01-10 07:19:30.1 |       3 |   4
 2017-01-10 07:19:31.0 |       5 |   5
 2017-01-10 07:19:32.0 |       3 |   6
 2017-01-10 07:19:33.1 |       5 |   7
 2017-01-10 07:19:35.0 |       5 |   7
 2017-01-10 07:19:36.1 |       5 |   7
 2017-01-10 07:19:37.1 |       5 |   7
(16 rows)
```

Then we wrap in a subselect `GROUP BY` and `ORDER` and select the min max  (range)

```
SELECT id_type, grp, min(date), max(date)
FROM (
  .. stuff
) AS g
GROUP BY id_type, grp
ORDER BY min(date);
```

Answer (score 18):

#### 1. Window functions plus subqueries

Count the steps to form groups, similar to [Evan's idea](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/166395/3684), with modifications and fixes:

```
SELECT id_type
     , min(date) AS begin
     , max(date) AS end
     , count(*)  AS row_ct  -- optional addition
FROM  (
   SELECT date, id_type, count(step OR NULL) OVER (ORDER BY date) AS grp
   FROM  (
      SELECT date, id_type
           , lag(id_type, 1, id_type) OVER (ORDER BY date) <> id_type AS step
      FROM   tmp
      ) sub1
   ) sub2
GROUP  BY id_type, grp
ORDER  BY min(date);
```

This assumes involved columns are **`NOT NULL`**. Else you need to do more.

Also assuming `date` to be defined **`UNIQUE`**, else you need to add a tiebreaker to the `ORDER BY` clauses get deterministic results. Like: `ORDER BY date, id`.

Detailed explanation (answer to very similar question):

- [Select longest continuous sequence](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35380/select-longest-continuous-sequence/35389#35389)

Note in particular:

- In related cases, [`lag()` with 3 parameters](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html#FUNCTIONS-WINDOW-TABLE) can be essential to cover the corner case of the first (or last) row elegantly. (The 3rd param is used as default if there is no previous (next) row.

  ```
    lag(id_type, 1, id_type) OVER ()
  ```

Since we are only interested in an actual *change* of `id_type` (`TRUE`), it does not matter in this particular case. `NULL` and `FALSE` both don't count as `step`.

- `count(step OR NULL) OVER (ORDER BY date)` is the shortest syntax that also works in Postgres 9.3 or older. `count()` only counts non-null values ...

In modern Postgres, the cleaner, equivalent syntax would be:

```
    count(step) FILTER (WHERE step) OVER (ORDER BY date)
```

Details:

- [For absolute performance, is SUM faster or COUNT?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27558/for-absolute-performance-is-sum-faster-or-count/27572#27572)

#### 2. Subtract two window functions, one subquery

Similar to [Erik's idea](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/166625/3684) with modifications:

```
SELECT min(date) AS begin
     , max(date) AS end
     , id_type
FROM  (
   SELECT date, id_type
        , row_number() OVER (ORDER BY date)
        - row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY id_type ORDER BY date) AS grp
   FROM   tmp
   ) sub
GROUP  BY id_type, grp
ORDER  BY min(date);
```

If `date` is defined `UNIQUE`, like I mention above, `dense_rank()` would be pointless, since the result is the same as for `row_number()` and the latter is substantially cheaper.

If `date` is *not* defined `UNIQUE` (and we don't know that the only duplicates are on `(date, id_type)`), all of these queries are pointless, since the result is arbitrary.

Also, a subquery is typically cheaper than a CTE in Postgres. Only use CTEs when you *need* them.

Related answers with more explanation:

- [GROUP BY and aggregate sequential numeric values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8014577/939860)
- [Group by repeating attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14016575/939860)
- [GROUP BY uninterrupted sequence of logs for same location](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/112846/group-by-uninterrupted-sequence-of-logs-for-same-location/112898#112898)

In related cases where we already have a running number in the table, we can make do with a single window function:

- [Rank based on sequence of dates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20064303/939860)

#### 3. Top performance with plpgsql function

Since this question has become unexpectedly popular, I'll add another solution to demonstrate top performance.

SQL has many sophisticated tools to create solutions with short and elegant syntax. But a declarative language has its limits for more complex requirements that involve procedural elements.

A procedural solution with a ***server-side function*** is faster for this than anything posted so far because it only needs a **single sequential scan** over the table and a **single sort operation**. If a fitting index is available, even just a single index-only scan.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_tmp_groups()
  RETURNS TABLE (id_type int, grp_begin timestamp, grp_end timestamp)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _row  tmp;                       -- use table type for row variable
BEGIN
   FOR _row IN
      TABLE tmp ORDER BY date       -- add more columns for deterministic order 
   LOOP
      CASE _row.id_type = id_type 
      WHEN TRUE THEN                -- same group continues
         grp_end := _row.date;      -- remember last date so far
      WHEN FALSE THEN               -- next group starts
         RETURN NEXT;               -- return result for last group
         id_type   := _row.id_type;
         grp_begin := _row.date;
         grp_end   := _row.date;
      ELSE                          -- NULL for 1st row
         id_type   := _row.id_type; -- remember row data for starters
         grp_begin := _row.date;
         grp_end   := _row.date;
      END CASE;
   END LOOP;

   RETURN NEXT;                     -- return last result row      
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM f_tmp_groups();
```

Test with:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, TIMING OFF)  -- to focus on total performance
SELECT * FROM  f_tmp_groups();
```

You could make the function generic with polymorphic types and pass table type and column names. Details:

- [Refactor a PL/pgSQL function to return the output of various SELECT queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11751557/939860)

If you don't want to or cannot persist a function for this, it would even pay to create a temporary function on the fly. Costs a few ms.

- [How to create a temporary function in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4990622/939860)

---

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=27be54c8d2a185787cf39e247e5798f3)* - comparing performance for all three. (Building on [Jack's test case](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/166374/grouping-or-window/166397?noredirect=1#comment322002_166397), modified.)

[dbfiddle for Postgres 8.4](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=297912cdbfbd4b17f0e4864698b62363), where performance differences are even bigger. (Not operational any more.)

Comment: Read this a few times - still unsure of what you're talking about with the three argument lag or when you'd have to use `count(x or null)` or even what it's doing there. Perhaps you could show some samples where it *is* required, because it's not required here. And, what would key the requirement to cover those corner cases. BTW, I changed my downvote to the upvote just for the pl/pgsql example. That's really cool. (But, generally I'm against answers that summarize other answers or cover corner cases -- though I hate to say that this is a corner case because I don't understand it).

Comment: I would put them in two seperate self-answered questions because I'm sure I'm not the only one wondering what `count(x or null)` does. I'll be happy to ask both questions if you would prefer.

Comment: Here is one question [In what case is a `count(x or null)` needed in the Gaps and Islands?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/167096/2639)

Answer (score 7):

You can do this as a simple subtraction of `ROW_NUMBER()` operations (or if your dates are not unique, though still unique per `id_type`, then you can use `DENSE_RANK()` instead, though it will be a more expensive query):

```
WITH IdTypes AS (
   SELECT
      date,
      id_type,
      Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY date)
         - Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY id_type ORDER BY date)
         AS Seq
   FROM
      tmp
)
SELECT
   Min(date) AS begin,
   Max(date) AS end,
   id_type
FROM IdTypes
GROUP BY id_type, Seq
ORDER BY begin
;
```

[See this work at DB Fiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=36f91ebacfe7dbc4d9b51aefb70d4b5f)
(or see the [DENSE_RANK version](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=a0b1f164476c28ddbca78de83c758dfd))

Result:

```
begin                  end                    id_type
---------------------  ---------------------  -------
2017-01-10 07:19:21    2017-01-10 07:19:25    3
2017-01-10 07:19:26    2017-01-10 07:19:26    5
2017-01-10 07:19:27.1  2017-01-10 07:19:27.1  3
2017-01-10 07:19:28    2017-01-10 07:19:29    5
2017-01-10 07:19:30.1  2017-01-10 07:19:30.1  3
2017-01-10 07:19:31    2017-01-10 07:19:31    5
2017-01-10 07:19:32    2017-01-10 07:19:32    3
2017-01-10 07:19:33.1  2017-01-10 07:19:37.1  5
```

Logically, you can think of this as a simple `DENSE_RANK()` with a `PREORDER BY`, that is, you want the `DENSE_RANK` of all the items that are ranked together, and you want them ordered by the dates, you just have to deal with the pesky problem of the fact that at each change in the date, `DENSE_RANK` will increment. You do that by using the expression as I showed you above. Imagine if you had this syntax: `DENSE_RANK() OVER (PREORDER BY date, ORDER BY id_type)` where the `PREORDER` is excluded from the ranking calculation and only the `ORDER BY` is counted.

Note that it's important to `GROUP BY` both the generated `Seq` column as well as the `id_type` column. `Seq` is NOT unique by itself, there can be overlaps--you must also group by `id_type`.

For further reading on this topic:

- [Detect changes between row values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13618019/57611)—read the **See It For Yourself** section.
- [Or this simpler explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25238315/select-distinct-of-a-column-and-order-by-date-column-but-without-showing-the-dat/25238476#25238476)

That first link gives you some code you can use if you wanted the begin or end date to be the same as the previous or next period's end/begin date (so there are no gaps). Plus other versions that could assist you in your query. Though they have to be translated from SQL Server syntax...

Answer (score 6):

On Postgres 8.4 you can use a [RECURSIVE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/queries-with.html) function.

**How do they do it**

The recursive function adds a level to each different id_type, by selecting dates one by one on descending order.

```
       date           | id_type | lv
--------------------------------------
2017-01-10 07:19:21.0      3       8
2017-01-10 07:19:22.0      3       8
2017-01-10 07:19:23.1      3       8
2017-01-10 07:19:24.1      3       8
2017-01-10 07:19:25.0      3       8
2017-01-10 07:19:26.0      5       7
2017-01-10 07:19:27.1      3       6
2017-01-10 07:19:28.0      5       5
2017-01-10 07:19:29.0      5       5
2017-01-10 07:19:30.1      3       4
2017-01-10 07:19:31.0      5       3
2017-01-10 07:19:32.0      3       2
2017-01-10 07:19:33.1      5       1
2017-01-10 07:19:35.0      5       1
2017-01-10 07:19:36.1      5       1
2017-01-10 07:19:37.1      5       1
```

Then use MAX(date), MIN(date) grouping by level, id_type to get the desired result.

```
with RECURSIVE rdates as 
(
    (select   date, id_type, 1 lv 
     from     yourTable
     order by date desc
     limit 1
    )
    union
    (select    d.date, d.id_type,
               case when r.id_type = d.id_type 
                    then r.lv 
                    else r.lv + 1 
               end lv    
    from       yourTable d
    inner join rdates r
    on         d.date < r.date
    order by   date desc
    limit      1)
)
select   min(date) StartDate,
         max(date) EndDate,
         id_type
from     rdates
group by lv, id_type
;

+---------------------+---------------------+---------+
| startdate           |       enddate       | id_type |
+---------------------+---------------------+---------+
| 10.01.2017 07:19:21 | 10.01.2017 07:19:25 |    3    |
| 10.01.2017 07:19:26 | 10.01.2017 07:19:26 |    5    |
| 10.01.2017 07:19:27 | 10.01.2017 07:19:27 |    3    |
| 10.01.2017 07:19:28 | 10.01.2017 07:19:29 |    5    |
| 10.01.2017 07:19:30 | 10.01.2017 07:19:30 |    3    |
| 10.01.2017 07:19:31 | 10.01.2017 07:19:31 |    5    |
| 10.01.2017 07:19:32 | 10.01.2017 07:19:32 |    3    |
| 10.01.2017 07:19:33 | 10.01.2017 07:19:37 |    5    |
+---------------------+---------------------+---------+
```

Check it: http://rextester.com/WCOYFP6623

Answer (score 5):

Here is another method, which is similar to Evan's and Erwin's in that it uses LAG to determine islands. It differs from those solutions in that it uses only one level of nesting, no grouping, and considerably more window functions:

```
SELECT
  id_type,
  date AS begin,
  COALESCE(
    LEAD(prev_date) OVER (ORDER BY date ASC),
    last_date
  ) AS end
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      id_type,
      date,
      LAG(date) OVER (ORDER BY date ASC) AS prev_date,
      MAX(date) OVER () AS last_date,
      CASE id_type
        WHEN LAG(id_type) OVER (ORDER BY date ASC)
        THEN 0
        ELSE 1
      END AS is_start
    FROM
      tmp
  ) AS derived
WHERE
  is_start = 1
ORDER BY
  date ASC
;
```

The `is_start` computed column in the nested SELECT marks the beginning of each island. Additionally, the nested SELECT exposes each row's previous date and the dataset's last date.

For rows that are the beginnings of their respective islands, the previous date effectively is the previous island's ending date. That is what the main SELECT uses it as. It picks only the rows matching the `is_start = 1` condition, and for each returned row it shows the row's own `date` as `begin` and the following row's `prev_date` as `end`. As the last row does not have a following row, `LEAD(prev_date)` returns a null for it, for which the COALESCE function substitutes the dataset's last date.

You can play with this solution [at dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=ae256f98a886cc984fb89f5175cbbc2b).

When introducing additional columns identifying the islands, you will probably want to introduce a PARTITION BY subclause to each window function's OVER clause. For instance, if you want to detect the islands within groups defined by a `parent_id`, the above query will probably need to look like this:

```
SELECT
  parent_id,
  id_type,
  date AS begin,
  COALESCE(
    LEAD(prev_date) OVER (PARTITION BY parent_id ORDER BY date ASC),
    last_date
  ) AS end
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      parent_id,
      id_type,
      date,
      LAG(date) OVER (PARTITION BY parent_id ORDER BY date ASC) AS prev_date,
      MAX(date) OVER (PARTITION BY parent_id) AS last_date,
      CASE id_type
        WHEN LAG(id_type) OVER (PARTITION BY parent_id ORDER BY date ASC)
        THEN 0
        ELSE 1
      END AS is_start
    FROM
      tmp
  ) AS derived
WHERE
  is_start = 1
ORDER BY
  date ASC
;
```

And if you decide to go with either Erwin's or Evan's solution, I believe a similar change will need to be added to it as well.

Answer (score 5):

More out of academic interest than as a practical solution, you can also achieve this with a [user-defined aggregate](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/xaggr.html). Like the other solutions, this will work even on Postgres 8.4, but as others have commented, please upgrade if you can.

The aggregate handles `null` as if it is a different `foo_type`, so runs of nulls would be given the same `grp` — that may or may not be what you want.

> ```
> create function grp_sfunc(integer[],integer) returns integer[] language sql as $$
>   select array[$1[1]+($1[2] is distinct from $2 or $1[3]=0)::integer,$2,1];
> $$;
> ```
>
> ```
> create function grp_finalfunc(integer[]) returns integer language sql as $$
>   select $1[1];
> $$;
> ```
>
> ```
> create aggregate grp(integer)(
>   sfunc = grp_sfunc
> , stype = integer[]
> , finalfunc = grp_finalfunc
> , initcond = '{0,0,0}'
> );
> ```

> ```
> select min(foo_at) begin_at, max(foo_at) end_at, foo_type
> from (select *, grp(foo_type) over (order by foo_at) from foo) z
> group by grp, foo_type
> order by 1;
> ```
>
> ```
> begin_at              | end_at                | foo_type
> :-------------------- | :-------------------- | -------:
> 2017-01-10 07:19:21   | 2017-01-10 07:19:25   |        3
> 2017-01-10 07:19:26   | 2017-01-10 07:19:26   |        5
> 2017-01-10 07:19:27.1 | 2017-01-10 07:19:27.1 |        3
> 2017-01-10 07:19:28   | 2017-01-10 07:19:29   |        5
> 2017-01-10 07:19:30.1 | 2017-01-10 07:19:30.1 |        3
> 2017-01-10 07:19:31   | 2017-01-10 07:19:31   |        5
> 2017-01-10 07:19:32   | 2017-01-10 07:19:32   |        3
> 2017-01-10 07:19:33.1 | 2017-01-10 07:19:37.1 |        5
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=5769b17ec5e809eee4e174bc75887b51)*

Answer (score 4):

This can be done with [`RECURSIVE CTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) to pass the "begin time" from one row to the next, and some extra (convenience) preparations.

This query returns the result you wish:

```
WITH RECURSIVE q AS
(
    SELECT
        id_type,
        "date",
        /* We compute next id_type for convenience, plus row_number */
        row_number()  OVER (w) AS rn,
        lead(id_type) OVER (w) AS next_id_type
    FROM
        t
    WINDOW
        w AS (ORDER BY "date") 
)
```

after the preparation... recursive part

```
, rec AS 
(
    /* Anchor */
    SELECT
        q.rn,
        q."date" AS "begin",
        /* When next_id_type is different from Look also at **next** row to find out whether we need to mark an end */
        case when q.id_type is distinct from q.next_id_type then q."date" END AS "end",
        q.id_type
    FROM
        q
    WHERE
        rn = 1

    UNION ALL

    /* Loop */
    SELECT
        q.rn,
        /* We keep copying 'begin' from one row to the next while type doesn't change */
        case when q.id_type = rec.id_type then rec.begin else q."date" end AS "begin",
        case when q.id_type is distinct from q.next_id_type then q."date" end AS "end",
        q.id_type
    FROM
        rec
        JOIN q ON q.rn = rec.rn+1
)
-- We filter the rows where "end" is not null, and project only needed columns
SELECT
    "begin", "end", id_type
FROM
    rec
WHERE
    "end" is not null ;
```

You can check this at http://rextester.com/POYM83542

This method doesn't scale well. For an 8_641 row table, it takes 7s, for a table twice that size, it takes 28s. A few samples more show execution times looking like O(n^2).

Evan Carrol's method takes less than 1s (i.e.: go for it!), and looks like O(n). Recursive queries are absolutely inefficient, and should be considered a last resort.