# Is WITH RECURSIVE the right tool for my task?

Tags: postgresql, window-functions, recursive, gaps-and-islands

Table setup:

```
create table users(id bigserial, group_id bigint);
insert into users(group_id) values (1), (1), (2), (1), (3), (3);
```

Query:

```
    WITH RECURSIVE r AS (
      SELECT users.id, users.group_id, 0 as i
      FROM users

      UNION 

      SELECT users.id, users.group_id
          , (CASE WHEN users.group_id = lag(users.group_id) over (order by users.id) 
                  THEN (r.i) 
                  ELSE (r.i+1) END) AS i 
       FROM users
       INNER JOIN r ON users.id = r.id
       WHERE r.i < 5)
    SELECT * FROM r;
```

I'm trying to iterate through user, and assign `i` if previous `group_id` value is equal to current, `i+1` otherwise, starting from 0.

However, this recursive query doesn't work as I expect, see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ad3b6/39

Comment: What is the output you expect? Without an `order by` there is no such thing as the "previous" row

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I'll assume the set is meant to be ordered by the serial `id` (though that's missing from the query).

Answer (score 2):

Simpler and faster (and correct) with window functions and a subquery:

```
SELECT id, group_id, count(step) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS i
FROM  (
   SELECT id, group_id
        , lag(group_id, 1, group_id) OVER (ORDER BY id) <> group_id OR NULL AS step
   FROM   users
   ) sub;
```

> ```
> id|group_id| i
> --+--------+--
>  1|       1| 0
>  2|       1| 0
>  3|       2| 1
>  4|       1| 2
>  5|       3| 3
>  6|       3| 3
> ```

It's the same basic logic as discussed and explained in depth here (just simpler, without aggregation of rows):

- [Grouping or Window](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/166374/grouping-or-window/166397)

There are also working solutions with a recursive CTE like you tried under the linked question, but those are substantially slower and more complex.

Andthere is also a plpgsql solution. Also more complex, but fastest.
Here is an optimized variant for your simple case without aggregation:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_users_i()
  RETURNS TABLE (id bigint, group_id bigint, i bigint) AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _last_group_id bigint;                 -- aux var to remember last group
BEGIN
   i := 0;                                -- init to 0

   FOR id, group_id IN
      SELECT u.id, u.group_id FROM users u ORDER BY u.id
   LOOP
      IF group_id <> _last_group_id THEN  -- next group starts
         i := i + 1;
      END IF;

      _last_group_id := group_id;         -- remember last group
      RETURN NEXT;
   END LOOP;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM f_users_i();
```

Same result.

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=80f5c50d5905b66be1bfc46f15e96ce4)* (Postgres 9.6).
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e3465/1) (the same, based on your fiddle on Postgres 9.3).

Aside: I doubt you need `bigint` for users and groups. Can probably all be just `integer`.