# In what case is a count(x or null) needed in Gaps and Islands?

Tags: postgresql, count, null, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

In [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/166397), Erwin Brandstetter says:

> `count(step OR NULL) OVER (ORDER BY date)` is the shortest syntax that also works in Postgres 9.3 or older. `count()` only counts non-null values. In modern Postgres, the cleaner, equivalent syntax would be:
>
> ```
> count(step) FILTER (WHERE step) OVER (ORDER BY date)
> ```

I'm unsure of why `count(step OR NULL)` is preferred though. In my query, I do the following. *I renamed my variables to match his while maintaining the syntax.*

```
CASE WHEN lag(id_type) OVER (ORDER BY date) <> id_type THEN 1 END AS step
```

We're counting the values returned by that. Note, **that the case can only return 1, or null.**

- if the two ARE NOT equal, 1 is returned.
- if they are equal, it returns null which isn't counted.

Erwin's answer has:

> This assumes involved columns are **`NOT NULL`**. Else you need to do more.

So I'm even more confused. What is the point of adding `count(step OR NULL)` what is this protecting our query against?

Could anyone break this down and perhaps show two examples with data wherein only one of them - the one with - `count(x OR NULL)` works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can see, it's all about handling `false` **not** `null`. With code and some background on vanilla `count()`: the case `count(x OR NULL)` catches is when `x=false`

1. **Vanilla `count()`** catches false. This will return 1.

   ```
   SELECT count(x)
   FROM ( VALUES (false) ) AS t(x);
   ```
2. **`CASE` folding**, folds false into null which, unlike false, `count()` excludes. This will return 0.

   ```
   SELECT count(x)
   FROM ( VALUES (CASE WHEN false THEN 1 END) ) AS t(x);
   ```
3. **Short-circuit** method evaluates `false OR null`, and thus `null` which `count()` excludes. This will return 0.

   ```
   SELECT count(x OR NULL)
   FROM ( VALUES (false) ) AS t(x);
   ```
4. **`FILTER`** method, evaluates x as bool. Skips false values and null values, sends everything else (true) to `count()`. This will return 0.

   ```
   SELECT count(x) FILTER (WHERE x)
   FROM ( VALUES (false) ) AS t(x);
   ```

## Conclusion

In my example, I use the method `2`, Erwin uses method `3` neither is a fix nor better; **neither is more optimal nor faster.**

Answer (score 5):

It's all about NULL handling. The expression `lag(id_type) OVER (ORDER BY date) <> id_type` evaluates to a boolean value, which can be `TRUE`, `FALSE` or `NULL`. If either the left or the right operand is NULL, we get NULL. There are various ways NULL can be introduced on either side:

- No previous (or next or similar in related cases) row.
- Column can be NULL in underlying table.
- An `OUTER JOIN` introduces NULL (no matching row found).
- An expression is involved that can evaluate to NULL.

There are various ways to fold *three-valued* logic to just *two* cases. A `CASE` statement, an `OR` expression etc. Related answer with details:

- [Select longest continuous sequence](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35380/select-longest-continuous-sequence/35389#35389)

Here is a comparison of the involved techniques, plus (updated) benchmark. Basically, they all perform the same, it's a cheap operation. The aggregate `FILTER` clause, introduced Postgres 9.4, seems a bit faster in the updated benchmark:

- [For absolute performance, is SUM faster or COUNT?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27558/for-absolute-performance-is-sum-faster-or-count/27572#27572)
- [Return counts for multiple ranges in a single SELECT statement](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/93510/return-counts-for-multiple-ranges-in-a-single-select-statement/93522#93522)

There is no case `wherein only one of them works`, the techniques are interchangeable. What to count or sum *exactly* depends on details of setup and requirements. In this case we only count `TRUE` - as long as the underlying table or query yields all non-null values (the corner case of the first row is open for debate).

And this case only requires a simple comparison. Related cases need to look at the previous or next value more closely. Then it may come in handy to provide a *default* value as 3rd parameter to `lag()` or `lead()`.