# How to optimize query with having and group

Tags: mysql

My Task is to optimize a query, which should check for data inconsistency: Return all leads ids with more than one entries and multiple is_first flag.

```
| id | lead_id | is_first| (other data) |
|----|---------|---------|-------- ...
|   1|       20|        1|...
|   2|       20|        0|
|   3|       21|        1|
|   4|       21|        0|
|   5|       21|        1|
|   6|       22|        1|
```

So this dataset should return 21. (20 ok, because is_first is only true/1 once)

Old Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s1.lead_id as lead_id
FROM history as s1
INNER JOIN history as s2 ON
  s1.is_first = 1 AND
  s2.is_first = 1 AND
    s1.id != s2.id AND
    s1.lead_id = s2.lead_id;
```

New Query: I already increased performance somewhat with this query

```
SELECT history.lead_id AS lead_id
FROM history
WHERE is_first = 1 GROUP BY lead_id
HAVING count(lead_id) != 1;
```

But I feel it's not end of the line. Any recommendations?

Comment: Try using `HAVING count(lead_id) > 1` as count cannot have a value <=0. Can you post the actual schema including indexes and the query plan so we can work out if there is anything else that is possible on the dataset.

Comment: "So this dataset should return 21. (20 ok, because is_first is only true/1 once)"... "20 ok" what does that even mean, can you draw up the desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you dont have it already, you could create a **index on both fields**: **is_first** and **lead_id**;

---

If it's a table with few record you won't see much difference, so I always recommend to check the statistics from the query.

Comment: Well... sometimes its better to find another way. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is something like this..

```
CREATE TABLE history(id int, lead_id int, is_first bool);
INSERT INTO history(id,lead_id,is_first)
VALUES
  ( 1, 20, 1 ),
  ( 2, 20, 0 ),
  ( 3, 21, 1 ),
  ( 4, 21, 0 ),
  ( 5, 21, 1 ),
  ( 6, 22, 1 );

SELECT *
FROM history AS h1
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM history AS h2
  WHERE h1.lead_id = h2.lead_id
  GROUP BY lead_id
  HAVING count(is_first OR NULL) > 1
);
+------+---------+----------+
| id   | lead_id | is_first |
+------+---------+----------+
|    3 |      21 |        1 |
|    4 |      21 |        0 |
|    5 |      21 |        1 |
+------+---------+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If you just want the `lead_id` of `21`

```
SELECT lead_id FROM history
GROUP BY lead_id
HAVING count(is_first OR NULL) > 1;
```

Comment: Why the `OR NULL`?

Comment: @joanolo it's not strictly needed because you can just use `sum()` with MySQL (you can't with PostgreSQL). This is for two reasons: count() counts nulls, sum ignore them. In MySQL sum counts true as one. In PostgreSQL you have to write a `CASE` statement which is longer. This may help in understanding it: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/167167/2639