# Selecting row grouped by an "add-on" indicator

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, gaps-and-islands

I have a (pre-existing, no I did not design it like this!) schema / dataset like this:

```
CREATE TABLE t(id,name,seq,addon,kind)
AS VALUES
    ( 1234::int, 'A' , 345::int, 'f'::bool, 'c'  ),
    ( 1235     , NULL, 346     , 't'      , NULL ),
    ( 1236     , NULL, 347     , 't'      , NULL ),
    ( 2345     , 'B' , 348     , 'f'      , 'x'  ),
    ( 2346     , NULL, 349     , 't'      , NULL ),
    ( 3456     , 'C' , 350     , 'f'      , 'c'  ),
    ( 3457     , NULL, 351     , 't'      , NULL );
```

Where:

1. The "id" field is just a SQL sequence (order not guaranteed)
2. The "seq" field is guaranteed to be sequential throughout the table, e.g. table is normally sorted on this column.
3. The "addon" field is indicating a group of related entries, e.g. TRUE entries are related to the nearest FALSE entry with a lower "seq".

I want to SELECT all the rows with "kind" = 'x' and all of their associated "addon" rows, without getting any other "addon" rows for other kinds.

So for instance:

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE kind = 'x' AND ???
```

Would give me:

```
  id  | name | seq  |addon | kind |
------+------+------+------+------+...
 2345 | "B"  | 348  |  f   | "x"  |
 2346 |      | 349  |  t   |      |
```

I have PostgreSQL 9.6...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to create a real grouping. Here we use a Window Function `count(x)` which counts all things `NOT NULL`. Try it with this simplified example,

```
SELECT count(a) OVER ()
FROM ( VALUES (true),(false) ) AS t(a);
```

In order to count just what we want, we use `OR` which evaluates the rhs if the lhs is not `true`. So here we test if the row `IS FALSE` (returning true if the value is false), if the condition does not evaluate to true (meaning the value is true or null) we return `null` (so `count(x)` skips it). here is the full query,

```
SELECT *,
  count((addon IS FALSE) OR NULL) OVER (ORDER BY seq) AS grp
FROM t

  id  | name | seq | addon | kind | grp 
------+------+-----+-------+------+-----
 1234 | A    | 345 | f     | c    |   1
 1235 |      | 346 | t     |      |   1
 1236 |      | 347 | t     |      |   1
 2345 | B    | 348 | f     | x    |   2
 2346 |      | 349 | t     |      |   2
 3456 | C    | 350 | f     | c    |   3
 3457 |      | 351 | t     |      |   3
(7 rows)
```

now you can easily do anything you want..

```
WITH t AS (
  SELECT *,
    count((addon IS FALSE) OR NULL) OVER (ORDER BY seq) AS grp
  FROM t
)
SELECT *
FROM t AS t1
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM t AS t2
  WHERE addon IS FALSE
    AND kind = 'x'
    AND t1.grp = t2.grp
)
ORDER BY seq;
```

To see this pattern elsewhere, check out the [gaps-and-islands](/questions/tagged/gaps-and-islands) and [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql), using [this search](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgaps-and-islands%5D+%5Bpostgresql%5D+is%3Aquestion)

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic example of [GROUPING OR WINDOWS](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/166374/grouping-or-window)

> ```
> create table test(id int, name varchar(10), seq int, addon bool, kind varchar(10));
> insert into test values
> ( 1234, 'A', 345, false, 'c'),
> ( 1235, null, 346, true, null),
> ( 1236, null, 347, true, null),
> ( 2345, 'B', 348, false, 'x'),
> ( 2346, null, 349, true, null),
> ( 3456, 'C', 350, false, 'c'),
> ( 3457, null, 351, true, null);
> ```

> ```
> with ctrst as
> (
>     select id, name, seq, addon, kind,
>            case when kind is not null then 1 end as rst
>     from   test
> )
> , ctgrp as
> (
>     select id, name, seq, kind,
>            count(rst) over (order by seq) as grp
>      from  ctrst
> )
> select id, name, seq, kind 
> from   ctgrp
> where  grp = (select grp from ctgrp where kind = 'x')
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
>   id | name | seq | kind
> ---: | :--- | --: | :---
> 2345 | B    | 348 | x   
> 2346 | null | 349 | null
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=49b6c7f7a6adaa059cf06bd994a77f16)*

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming from your example data that you can tell if a row is an 'addon' by checking if the `kind` field is null. If that's the case you can use a windowing `count` on `kind` to group the rows into 'islands':

> ```
> select id, name, seq, addon, kind
> from ( select *, max(kind) over (partition by grp) grp_kind
>        from ( select *, count(kind) over (order by seq) grp from t ) z ) z
> where grp_kind='x';
> ```
>
> ```
>   id | name | seq | addon | kind
> ---: | :--- | --: | :---- | :---
> 2345 | B    | 348 | f     | x   
> 2346 | null | 349 | t     | null
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=461d15bf00bad1e1b8bf22b5c8a1db94)*

If that assumption doesn't hold you can use `count(nullif(addon,true))` to the same effect, or `sum(1-addon::int)`:

> ```
> select id, name, seq, addon, kind
> from ( select *, max(kind) over (partition by grp) grp_kind
>        from ( select *, sum(1-addon::int) over (order by seq) grp from t ) z ) z
> where grp_kind='x';
> ```
>
> ```
>   id | name | seq | addon | kind
> ---: | :--- | --: | :---- | :---
> 2345 | B    | 348 | f     | x   
> 2346 | null | 349 | t     | null
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=17b5693a45dc40dea1676bc5049a83ef)*