# Add running count of specific state changes

Tags: postgresql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have a table in PostgreSQL with below fields, where timestamp is simplified as integers:

```
ts  status
1     m
2     m
3     i
4     s
5     s
6     i
7     i
8     m
9     s
10    m
```

I want to break then aggregate rows based on the presence of the 's' status, to spit out an additional column which I can use to easily group rows:

```
ts  status  flag
1     m      1
2     m      1
3     i      1
4     s      1
5     s      1
6     i      2
7     i      2
8     m      2
9     s      2
10    m      3
```

The dynamic column `flag` shall increment whenever `status` changes from 's' to something else.

I don't see a clear pattern to partition by. How to do this?

Comment: Please remember to always disclose your Postgres version. And typically also a table definition (`CREATE TABLE` statement). Example: It matters whether columns can be NULL ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two levels of [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html).
To keep the code short, you can combine the aggregate `FILTER` clause with the outer window function:

```
SELECT ts, status
     , 1 + count(*) FILTER (WHERE previous_status = 's' AND status <> 's')
                    OVER (ORDER BY ts) AS flag
FROM (
   SELECT *, lag(status) OVER (ORDER BY ts) AS previous_status
   FROM   tbl
   ) sub;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=c2e07c7a7f68b4c1e012afc947ce5e7b)*

Assuming current Postgres and all columns `NOT NULL`.
Related:

- [Return counts for multiple ranges in a single SELECT statement](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/93510/return-counts-for-multiple-ranges-in-a-single-select-statement/93522#93522)
- [Grouping or Window](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/166374/grouping-or-window/166397#166397)