# Select all before first break

Tags: postgresql, window-functions, postgresql-9.5

I have a table with three columns: `id, sort, name` in PostgreSQL 9.5 database.

I need to select all rows starting from `sort=1` and before the first break (ordered by `sort`).

For example I have:

```
id | sort | name
1  |   1  | 'ss'
2  |   2  | 'ss'
3  |   3  | 'ss'
4  |   4  | 'ss'
5  |   7  | 'ss'
6  |   8  | 'ss'
```

I want to select rows with `id=1,2,3,4`.

As you can see, there is a break in the `sort` sequence (`4-7`). So I only need the rows before this break.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

This will work for the special case:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table 
WHERE sort < (SELECT MIN(t.sort) 
              FROM your_table AS t
              LEFT JOIN your_table AS t2
                  ON t.sort = t2.sort+1 
              WHERE t2.sort IS NULL
                AND t.sort > (SELECT MIN(sort) FROM your_table))
```

Answer (score 1):

[Window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html) can help you there. Look for `lead` which will give you the next value by a given order. With them you can avoid self joins.

One solution would be:

```
-- Getting the next value
with ahead as ( 
    select id, sort, lead(sort) over (order by sort) sort_lead, "name" 
    from test1
),
-- Find where we have the first gap
gap as (
    select min(sort) sort_limit from ahead
    where sort_lead - sort > 1
)
-- Select everything starting from 1 until the gap
select * from test1 
where sort between 1 and (select sort_limit from gap)
order by sort;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `sort` to be *unique*, just look at the delta between the [window function `row_number()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html) and `sort`:

```
SELECT *
FROM  (SELECT *, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY sort) AS grp FROM tbl) sub
WHERE  sort = grp;
```

`sort` gets out of sync at the first gap.

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d8ba8e/3)

Detailed explanation:

- [Select longest continuous sequence](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35380/select-longest-continuous-sequence/35389#35389)