# How to select blocks with sequential data and aggregate the ids

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have the following table:

```
 id(int) startDate(timestamp)         endDate(timestamp)            plan_id(int)  planned(bool)  machine(int)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  2005  '2019-01-16 08:29:24.872736'  '2019-01-16 08:30:23.529706'    34          true              6
  2004  '2019-01-16 08:19:28.011148'  '2019-01-16 08:29:22.680828'    34          true              6
  2003  '2019-01-16 08:18:27.074312'  '2019-01-16 08:19:25.753475'    34          true              6
  2002  '2019-01-16 08:08:30.206288'  '2019-01-16 08:18:24.856308'    34          true              6
  2001  '2019-01-16 08:07:29.163124'  '2019-01-16 08:08:27.949013'    34          true              6
  2000  '2019-01-16 07:59:03.221309'  '2019-01-16 08:00:14.654391'    null        false             7
  1999  '2019-01-16 08:00:00.986367'  '2019-01-16 08:00:03.221309'    null        false             6
  1998  '2019-01-16 07:57:30.711044'  '2019-01-16 07:59:58.778444'    null        false             6
  1997  '2019-01-16 07:56:32.466508'  '2019-01-16 07:57:28.489287'    null        false             6
  1996  '2019-01-16 07:50:06.887349'  '2019-01-16 07:56:30.237725'    null        false             6
  1995  '2019-01-16 07:46:34.327582'  '2019-01-16 07:50:04.619592'    33          true              6
  1994  '2019-01-16 07:45:33.813483'  '2019-01-16 07:46:32.014849'    33          true              6
  1993  '2019-01-16 07:24:39.267365'  '2019-01-16 07:39:23.786911'    null        false             6
  1992  '2019-01-16 07:23:39.646218'  '2019-01-16 07:24:37.093414'    null        false             6
  1991  '2019-01-16 07:13:41.166337'  '2019-01-16 07:23:37.403375'    null        false             6
  1990  '2019-01-16 07:12:39.961234'  '2019-01-16 07:13:38.907838'    null        false             6
  1989  '2019-01-16 07:10:46.984236'  '2019-01-16 07:12:37.647108'    null        false             6
  1988  '2019-01-15 17:05:59.832834'  '2019-01-15 17:08:21.603931'    31          true              6
  1987  '2019-01-15 17:04:59.567046'  '2019-01-15 17:05:57.565188'    31          true              6
  1986  '2019-01-15 17:00:01.411266'  '2019-01-15 17:10:57.255158'    31          true              7
```

I have to select the IDs of the blocks of unplanned records for a specific machine. I have been trying using window function, unfortunately, I couldn't work out the logic of it!

The problem here is that since we have different machines, we cannot rely on sequential ids, just that the `endDate` of a sequence is very close to next `startDate` (it is ok to set a tolerance constant e.g. 3 seconds).

I would like to have a query where the result would be: the min `startDate`, the max `endDate` and the IDs of the block. For this sample with `machine = 6`, it would be:

```
blockStartDate                blockEndDate                  ids
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
"2019-01-16 07:50:06.887349" "2019-01-16 08:00:03.221309" [1999,1998,1997,1996]
"2019-01-16 07:10:46.984236" "2019-01-16 07:39:23.786911" [1989,1990,1991,1992,1993]
```

Note that the answer, in this case, has sequential IDs but this is not always the case. I am working on providing real data where 2 machines are producing data at the same time and the ids become useless.

Comment: Do you need min & max date of each block of un-planned id's or is it necessary to calculate date_diff of each row and consider a block those where enddate - stardate < 3 s?

Comment: min & max date of each block! 
I just mention the difference of 3s between the endDate and the startDate of NEXT RECORD because this is the only criteria that I could think that makes the data sequential i.e how you can know that this record belongs to a specific block.

Comment: If there was only *one* machine, would sequential IDs indicate a continuous block, no matter the actual gap between end & start, only interrupted by "planned" rows?

Comment: Yes, this is right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If blocks are defined by continuously incrementing IDs (or continuously incrementing `startDate` or `endDate`, same principle) with the same `machine` and `NOT planned`, *ignoring* possible gaps, only separated by rows with `planned IS NOT FALSE`, then there is no need to speculate with tolerance between end & begin and you can just use this:

```
SELECT min(startDate) AS block_start_date
     , max(endDate)   AS block_end_date
     , array_agg(id)  AS ids
FROM (
   SELECT id, startDate, endDate, planned
        , row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id)
        - row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY planned ORDER BY id) AS grp
   FROM   tbl
   WHERE  machine = 6
   ORDER  BY id  --  to get sorted arrays
   ) sub
WHERE  NOT planned
GROUP  BY grp;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=f75fda74a8fcfbbeac76acd737ca28b5)* (building on McNets' fiddle)

Basics:

- [Select longest continuous sequence](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35380/select-longest-continuous-sequence/35389#35389)

Note, this returns uniformly sorted arrays, unlike your example with varying sort order.

Aside: `planned` seems to say no more than `plan_id IS NOT NULL`. If so, you can remove the redundant column completely. Redundant columns only add cost.

Answer (score 0):

Basically it set a reset point each time there is a difference greater than 3 seconds between `startDate` and previous `endDate`.

Then set blocks (groups) by getting the sum of each reset point, and finally returns MIN/MAX dates and an array with the aggregated id's of every group.

```
WITH x AS
(
SELECT
    id,
    startDate,
    endDate,
    machine,
    case when
         date_part('second', 
                   startDate -  
                   coalesce(lag(endDate) over (partition by machine order by machine, startDate), 
                            startDate - interval '10' second)) > 3
         then 1 else 0 end as reset

FROM
    tbl
WHERE
    machine = 6
    AND planned = false
ORDER BY
    machine,
    startDate
), y AS
 (
 SELECT 
     id, startDate, endDate,
     sum(reset) over (partition by machine order by machine, startDate) grp
 FROM
     x
 )
 SELECT
     MIN(startDate) blockStartDate,
     MAX(endDate) blockEndDate,
     array_agg(id) ids
 FROM
     y
 GROUP BY
     grp
 ORDER BY
     grp;
```

> ```
> blockstartdate             | blockenddate               | ids                       
> :------------------------- | :------------------------- | :-------------------------
> 2019-01-16 07:10:46.984236 | 2019-01-16 07:39:23.786911 | {1989,1990,1991,1992,1993}
> 2019-01-16 07:50:06.887349 | 2019-01-16 08:00:03.221309 | {1996,1997,1998,1999}
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=8d1e1d830648c17cea3c8783e3c83ce1)*

Comment: Woow, Thank you so much!!! There was some wrong grouping when I tested in the complete table but I was able to fix it by changing `date_part('second',`  to `extract(epoch from `.