# Count number of occurences per location per hour in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, table, count

I have a dataset in Postgres of boat locations  on waterways. Here is a sample of the table:

| boat_id | ts | waterway_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Boat_A | 2019-01-01 16:29:11 | WW_01 |
| Boat_A | 2019-01-01 17:03:04 | WW_02 |
| Boat_B | 2019-01-01 16:11:34 | WW_01 |
| Boat_B | 2019-01-01 16:13:45 | WW_01 |
| Boat_B | 2019-01-01 17:05:13 | WW_01 |
| Boat_C | 2019-01-01 16:03:00 | WW_01 |
| Boat_C | 2019-01-01 16:09:50 | WW_02 |
| Boat_C | 2019-01-01 16:16:22 | WW_01 |
| Boat_C | 2019-01-01 16:45:44 | WW_01 |

boat_id is the unique identification of the boat, ts is timestamp and water_id is the unique identifier of the waterway.
I would like to know for each hour in the dataset how many boats passed each waterway. The result should look like this:

| waterway_id | report_ts | passage_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| WW_01 | 2019-01-01 00:00 | 3 |
| WW_01 | 2019-01-01 01:00 | 1 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| WW_01 | 2019-12-31 23:00 | 5 |
| WW_02 | 2019-01-01 00:00 | 13 |
| WW_02 | 2019-01-01 01:00 | 11 |
| ... | ... | ... |

The raw data contains the position of boats, not passages. Thus:

1. Multiple datapoints of the same boat on the same waterway should be counted as a single passage.
2. If a boat has been on another waterway and comes back it should be counted as another passage.
3. If a boat is detected on the same waterway in multiple hours, without being on anther waterway in between, it should be counted as a single passage in the hour it was first detected.
   In the example data above, boat_A makes 1 passage on waterway WW_01 at 16h and 1 on WW_02 at 17h, boat_b makes 1 passages on WW_01 at 16h (there is no passage at 18h because it did not go to antoher waterway in between), boat_C makes 2 passages on waterway WW_01 at 16h and 1 passage on WW_02 at 16h. In a table (waterway-hour combinations with 0 passages do not have to be included in the result):

| waterway_id | report_ts | passage_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| WW_01 | 2019-01-01 16:00 | 4 |
| WW_02 | 2019-01-01 16:00 | 1 |
| WW_02 | 2019-01-01 17:00 | 1 |

What should the query to get this result look like?
In my mind, it consists of two steps:

1. Computing unique passages per boat per waterway
2. Organizing these in a table as the example above

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/34ba2d/1)

Comment: When you have     (1, '2019-06-03 10:45:35', 'BAMST007') followed by (1, '2019-06-03 11:27:34', 'HERGR008'), does this mean that boat 1 was on BAMST007 at 11h on 3/6/2019 ?

Comment: @Thomas - why do you have a count of 0 for WW_01 2019-01-01 17:00? How many 0 counts do you want? When do they apply and when do they not apply?

Comment: The problem is not well defined, while [Gerard's question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/295951/count-number-of-occurences-per-location-per-hour-in-postgresql#comment578502_295951) remains unanswered. Also: If Boat_A is on WW_1 at 16:29 and on 18:29 (and no entries in between), does it count for 17:00? Please define what counts *exactly*. And define "each hour in the dataset", too. That leaves room for interpretation in a similar fashion.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille, this is correct. A 'passage' should be counted in the hour in which it was first sighted on a waterway.

Comment: @Vérace, the 0 counts do not have to be included. I changed this in the problem description

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, a boat that is detected on the same waterway across multiple hours, without being detected on another waterway in between, should be counted as a single passage in the hour of first detection. I added this to the problem description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all involved table columns `NOT NULL`.

Your added clarifications make it a much simpler problem.
This only counts the first hour of each passage:

```
SELECT waterway_id, date_trunc('hour', ts), count(*) AS count
FROM  (
   SELECT waterway_id, ts -- , boat_id
        , lag(waterway_id, 1, '') OVER (PARTITION BY boat_id ORDER BY ts) <> waterway_id AS switch
   FROM   boat_data
   ) sub
WHERE  switch  -- only the first ts of each passage
GROUP  BY 1, 2
ORDER  BY 1, 2;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b0360777529c299eed874bcbc9f68e1a)*

We just have to consider the first row after switching waterways for each boat. Identify that with the window function [`lag()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html). Using `lag(waterway_id, 1, '')` to suppress NULL for the first row in each partition. (Assuming that the empty string (`''`)  is distinct from any existing `waterway_id`.)
Then truncate to the full hour with [`date_trunc()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) and count. Vóila.

My original solution counts every hour of each passage, which is a lot more complex:

```
SELECT waterway_id, report_ts, count(*) AS count
FROM  (
   SELECT waterway_id
        , generate_series(date_trunc('hour', min(ts))
                        , max(ts)
                        , interval '1 hour') AS report_ts
   FROM  (
      SELECT *
           , count(switch) OVER (PARTITION BY boat_id ORDER BY ts) AS passage
      FROM  (
         SELECT boat_id, ts, waterway_id
              , lag(waterway_id) OVER (PARTITION BY boat_id ORDER BY ts) <> waterway_id OR NULL AS switch
         FROM   boat_data
         ) sub1
      ) sub2
   GROUP  BY boat_id, waterway_id, passage
   ) sub3
GROUP  BY waterway_id, report_ts
ORDER  BY waterway_id, report_ts;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b0360777529c299eed874bcbc9f68e1a)*

Related:

- [Select longest continuous sequence](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35380/select-longest-continuous-sequence/35389#35389)

Comment: I edited the question to improve clarity, based on your  and others' questions. I now made explicit that multiple detections across hours of the same boat on the same waterway, without detections on another waterway, shold be counted as a single passage in the hour of first detection. This is not yet implemented in your solution if I am correct.

Comment: I added a (much simpler!) solution for your updated question.

Answer (score 4):

Editing to address this (emphasis mine) which was not the case with the original request:

> In a table (waterway-hour ***combinations with 0 passages do not have to
> be included in the result)***:

#### Primary keys are important

But before we get into that, we need to make sure you have the right primary key defined on your data, which is `(Boat_Id,Timestamp)`.  Creating this gives us two things:

1. Non-conforming records are rejected (a `Boat` can't be in two places at once)
2. A B-Tree for efficiently locating prior records for each `Boat` using a method other than an analytic/windowing function

#### Getting Passages

To determine if a passage has occurred, we need to know the last position of each `Boat`, which we get through a correlated subquery searching for the entry with the greatest `Timestamp` less than the current `Timestamp`. Since we are only interested in `Boats` that have moved `Waterways`, we can exclude them from our result set.

```
SELECT
  BD.Waterway_ID
 ,date_trunc('hour',BD.TimeStamp) AS Timestamp
 ,COUNT(*) AS passage_count
FROM
  Boat_Data BD
LEFT JOIN
  Boat_Data PriorBD
    ON PriorBD.Boat_Id = BD.Boat_Id
        AND PriorBD.Timestamp =
          (
            SELECT
              MAX(TimeStamp)
            FROM
              Boat_Data
            WHERE
              Boat_Id = BD.Boat_Id
                AND TimeStamp < BD.Timestamp
         )
WHERE
  BD.Waterway_ID <> PriorBD.Waterway_Id
    OR PriorBD.Waterway_Id IS NULL
GROUP BY
  BD.Waterway_ID
 ,date_trunc('hour',BD.TimeStamp)
```

Alternately, you can use an analytical/windowing function as Erwin and Vérace have done.  I provide this as a "second solution" as analytic/windowing functions will **force a sort** in most instances<sup>1</sup>.  With larger amounts of data (or a different RDBMS), this may be a more expensive operation than just a self join with the proper primary key<sup>2</sup>.  As always, test.

```
SELECT
  BD.Waterway_ID
 ,date_trunc('hour',BD.TimeStamp) AS Timestamp
 ,COUNT(*) AS passage_count
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      Boat_Id
     ,Timestamp
     ,Waterway_Id
     ,CASE
        WHEN Waterway_Id <> LAG(Waterway_Id,1,'') OVER (PARTITION BY Boat_Id ORDER BY Timestamp) THEN 1
        ELSE 0
      END AS Passage_Ind
    FROM
      Boat_Data
  ) BD
WHERE
  BD.Passage_Ind = 1
GROUP BY
  BD.Waterway_ID
 ,date_trunc('hour',BD.TimeStamp)
;
```

Modified fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2cede7/2

<sup>1</sup> In SQL Server (and probably some other commercial platforms) a windowing/analytic function will not force a sort if the `PARTITION BY`
and `ORDER BY` statements match the sort order of the clustered index.  This is *not* the case in MySQL.

<sup>2</sup> The more recent versions of Postgres allow the INCLUDE statement to force specified non-key columns to be added to the B-Tree.  In this instance, you could include the `Waterway_Id` so the entire query could be fulfilled without touching the heap.

Answer (score 2):

This is part of a class of problems known as [Tabibito-san](https://www.toolbox.com/tech/data-management/blogs/tabibito-san-the-traveler-technique-in-sql-080216/) - well worth getting to know! This answer has been highly **revised** now that I think I've grasped your issue.

I changed your schema slightly - I removed the quoted identifiers - they are normally unnecessary and merely add complexity and make the queries less legible.

I also changed the field named `timestamp` to `bts` (boat timestamp) since it's not a good idea to use SQL keywords as variable names - it makes the SQL difficult to read also and interferes with debugging.

I also only kept data for `boat_1` - easier to reason about. The data I used are available on the fiddle and at the bottom of this post.

You can find the fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/93cc6/19) (oh, BTW, please **always** include your version of PostgreSQL in any questions)- unimportant for sqlfiddle.com (they only have 9.6), but if you use dbfiddle.uk (**many** more servers), it can be most helpful.

Revised DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE boat_data
    (boat_id int, bts timestamp, waterway_id varchar(9))
;
```

And then I ran the following query:

```
SELECT 
  boat_id, 
  MIN(bts) AS min_time, 
  MAX(bts) AS max_time, 
  waterway_id, 
  MIN(rn) AS min_rn,  
  MAX(rn) AS max_rn   
FROM
(
  SELECT boat_id, bts, waterway_id,
  ROW_NUMBER() 
    OVER 
      (
        PARTITION BY boat_id, waterway_id 
        ORDER BY boat_id, waterway_id
      ) AS rn
  FROM boat_data
  ORDER BY boat_id, waterway_id
) AS tab
GROUP BY boat_id, waterway_id;
```

Result (snipped for brevity):

```
boat_id min_time    max_time    waterway_id min_rn  max_rn
1   2019-06-03T10:27:25Z    2019-06-03T10:28:45Z    OSDOK003    1   4
1   2019-06-03T10:29:26Z    2019-06-03T10:29:54Z    OSDOK005    1   4
1   2019-06-03T10:32:26Z    2019-06-03T10:32:26Z    OUDSC001    1   1
1   2019-06-03T10:32:45Z    2019-06-03T10:34:34Z    OUDSC002    1   8
1   2019-06-03T10:30:35Z    2019-06-03T10:30:54Z    OUDSC003    1   3
```

You probably won't want **all** of this data - remove as appropriate!

There's a list of the "passages" giving all of the detail about them - as I said, more than necessary perhaps?

- What the first line is telling you is that for `boat_1`, its first passage started on waterway `OSDOK003` at `2019-06-03T10:27:25Z` and finished at `2019-06-03T10:28:45Z` and there were 4 measurements taken during that passage.
- Then it went on to waterway `OSDOK005` at time x and finished at time y - also 4 measurements.
- Then there was 1 measurement on waterway `OUDSC001`
- Followed by 8 measurements on waterway `OUDSC002`
- Then finally back to `OUDSC003` for 3 measurements.

I've "eye-balled" the data and this appears correct!

Now, you may have to take account of the date - in that case, just add `DATE(bts)` to the `SELECT` and the `GROUP BY`...

I've left some "artefacts" at the bottom of the fiddle so that you can see (more or less in reverse order) where my thinking was going - [Postgresql's window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/tutorial-window.html) are **very** powerful and well worth mastering - they will repay any effort 10 times over - esp. [ROW_NUMBER()](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-row_number/) - take a look at them and also LAG/LEAD (fiddle)...

========================================

Data for `boat_1` used in this answer.

```
INSERT INTO boat_data
    (boat_id, bts, waterway_id) 
VALUES
    (1, '2019-06-03 10:27:25', 'OSDOK003'),
    (1, '2019-06-03 10:27:54', 'OSDOK003'),
    (1, '2019-06-03 10:28:05', 'OSDOK003'),
    (1, '2019-06-03 10:28:45', 'OSDOK003'),
    (1, '2019-06-03 10:29:26', 'OSDOK005'),
    (1, '2019-06-03 10:29:35', 'OSDOK005'),
    (1, '2019-06-03 10:29:45', 'OSDOK005'),
    (1, '2019-06-03 10:29:54', 'OSDOK005'),
    (1, '2019-06-03 10:30:35', 'OUDSC003'),
    (1, '2019-06-03 10:30:45', 'OUDSC003'),
    (1, '2019-06-03 10:30:54', 'OUDSC003'),
    (1, '2019-06-03 10:32:26', 'OUDSC001'),
    (1, '2019-06-03 10:32:45', 'OUDSC002'),
    (1, '2019-06-03 10:32:55', 'OUDSC002'),
    (1, '2019-06-03 10:33:34', 'OUDSC002'),
    (1, '2019-06-03 10:33:45', 'OUDSC002'),
    (1, '2019-06-03 10:33:54', 'OUDSC002'),
    (1, '2019-06-03 10:34:04', 'OUDSC002'),
    (1, '2019-06-03 10:34:14', 'OUDSC002'),
    (1, '2019-06-03 10:34:34', 'OUDSC002');
```

Comment: Good improvements to the schema in fiddle.
The solution you provide is a good step but not exactly what I am aiming for. In the end I am not interested in the count of specific boats per waterway, but in the total number of passages of passages per waterway. This involves 2 extra steps:
1. convert the raw datapoints into unique passages (see original question)
2. sum the passages of all boats per waterway (and per hour, per day)

Comment: thanks for looking into this. With "passage" I mean a boat entering a waterway. Each line in the original data is a moment where a certain  boat was detected on a certain waterway. If there are multiple subsequent detections of the same boat on the same waterway it means it was detected multiple times, not that it passed this waterway multiple times. Thus, subsequent datapoints of the same boat on the same waterway should be counted as 1 passage. Only if a boat leaves a waterway (i.e. is detected on a different waterway) and then comes back it should be counted as another passage.

Comment: @Thomas  So, if boat 1 goes from waterway_1 to waterway_2 and then back to waterway_1, that's **3** passages and that's what you want to count?

Comment: Exactly. That is 2 passages for waterway_1 and 1 for waterway_2.