# How to select the latest continuous set of rows of a certain type?

Tags: postgresql, select, gaps-and-islands

(Using PostgreSQL) I'm looking to select the latest set of continuous (by date) rows that have a code 'A'. The latest row is always missing the "To Date" as it is assumed to be current. And there are never any gaps between the "To Date" of a row and the "From Date" of the row following it.

### Example Tables

Here I would like to select rows 2 and 3:

| Row Number | Code | From Date | To Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | B | 2021-05-01 |  |
| 2 | A | 2020-02-01 | 2021-04-30 |
| 3 | A | 2019-02-01 | 2020-01-31 |

Here I would like to select rows 1 and 2:

| Row Number | Code | From Date | To Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 2021-05-01 |  |
| 2 | A | 2020-02-01 | 2021-04-30 |
| 3 | B | 2019-02-01 | 2020-01-31 |

Here I would like to select rows 1 and 2:

| Row Number | Code | From Date | To Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 2021-09-07 |  |
| 2 | A | 2021-04-01 | 2021-09-06 |
| 3 | B | 2021-03-13 | 2021-03-31 |
| 4 | A | 2021-01-13 | 2021-03-12 |
| 5 | A | 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-12 |

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Please go to dbfiddle.uk and put in your tables' DDL your sample data DML and your desired result!

Comment: How do get the tables such that the most recent row is number 1? Shouldn't the tables be numbered the other way around?

Comment: @Vérace Sorry I was just adding the numbers to be able to indicate the rows I wanted to select as clearly as possible, the real table doesn't have those included

Comment: Check my answer - you have to be very careful about whether row_number is **cast-iron** guaranteed to match the dates - my solution **only** takes the dates into account - that's why I think it's better than the other one (and no offence meant) put forward?

Comment: Check out the second fiddle that I have - where I put any and all sorts of numbers into row_number...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To provide an answer to this problem, I did the following (all of the code below is on the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c5ec0a5d045aa60527f55788e5e6b077)):

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
  row_number INTEGER NOT NULL,
  code       TEXT    NOT NULL,
  from_date  DATE    NOT NULL,
  to_date    DATE    NULL
);
```

Populated with:

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES
(1, 'A', '2021-09-07', NULL),   
(2, 'A', '2021-04-01', '2021-09-06'),
(3, 'B', '2021-03-13', '2021-03-31'),
(4, 'A', '2021-01-13', '2021-03-12'),
(5, 'A', '2021-01-01', '2021-01-12');
```

Note the use of out of sequence `row_number`s - this can very easily happen in a frequently updated database - the resolution should only depend on those parts of the data that are independent of implementation details - i.e. the `from_date` in this case.

### Step 1:

Mark when a code change takes place - in order of `from_date DESC`.

```
SELECT 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY from_date DESC) AS rn,
  code, from_date, to_date,

  CASE 
    WHEN LAG(code) OVER (ORDER BY from_date DESC) = code THEN 0
    ELSE 1
  END AS code_change

FROM test;
```

Result:

```
rn  code    from_date   to_date     code_change
1   A      2021-09-07   NULL             1
2   A      2021-04-01   2021-09-06       0
3   B      2021-03-13   2021-03-31       1
4   A      2021-01-13   2021-03-12       1
5   A      2021-01-01   2021-01-12       0
```

### Second step:

Perform a cumulative sum over the `code_change` generated variable

```
SELECT
  *, SUM(code_change) OVER (ORDER BY from_date DESC)
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY from_date DESC) AS rn,
    code, from_date, to_date,

    CASE 
      WHEN LAG(code) OVER (ORDER BY from_date DESC) = code THEN 0
      ELSE 1
    END AS code_change

  FROM test
) AS tab_01
ORDER BY from_date DESC;
```

Result:

```
rn  code    from_date   to_date     code_change     sum
 1     A    2021-09-07  NULL            1            1
 2     A    2021-04-01  2021-09-06      0            1
 3     B    2021-03-13  2021-03-31      1            2
 4     A    2021-01-13  2021-03-12      1            3
 5     A    2021-01-01  2021-01-12      0            3
```

So, we now have a means of grouping the codes by sequence of the same code!

### Step 3:

We now obtain the `MIN(sum_cc)` to obtain the group with code `'A'`. This gives us the group with the most recent date(s) - because of the `ORDER BY from_date DESC`!

```
SELECT 
  code, MIN(sum_cc) 
FROM
(
SELECT
  *, SUM(code_change) OVER (ORDER BY from_date DESC) AS sum_cc
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY from_date DESC) AS rn,
    code, from_date, to_date,
...
... SQL snipped for brevity
...
) AS tab_02
WHERE code = 'A'
GROUP BY code;
```

Result:

```
code    min
   A      1
```

So, we no know that `'A'` with grouping = `1` that is the group of interest.

**VERY IMPORTANT** - this will work even if the `row_number` varialbe is **NOT** in sync with the date values - this can easily happen in a multi-user system - see this fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=72e34e451d05586f482bcedef9d91d1d).

### Step 4:

We now `JOIN` the result of step 4 back to the result from step 3 and obtain our final desired result as follows:

```
SELECT tab_03.*, tab_02.*
FROM
(
  SELECT
    *, SUM(tab_01.code_change) OVER (ORDER BY tab_01.from_date DESC) AS xx 
  FROM
  (
    SELECT 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY from_date DESC) AS rn,
      code, from_date, to_date,

      CASE 
        WHEN LAG(code) OVER (ORDER BY from_date DESC) = code THEN 0
        ELSE 1
      END AS code_change

    FROM test
  ) AS tab_01
) AS tab_03
JOIN 
(
  SELECT 
  code, MIN(sum_cc) AS yy
  FROM
  (
    SELECT
      *, SUM(code_change) OVER (ORDER BY from_date DESC) AS sum_cc
    FROM
    (
      SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY from_date DESC) AS rn,
        code, from_date, to_date,

        CASE 
          WHEN LAG(code) OVER (ORDER BY from_date DESC) = code THEN 0
          ELSE 1
        END AS code_change

      FROM test
    ) AS tab_01
    ORDER BY from_date DESC
  ) AS tab_02
  WHERE code = 'A'
  GROUP BY code
) AS tab_02
ON tab_03.xx = tab_02.yy;
```

Result:

```
row_number  code    from_date   to_date
         1     A    2021-09-07  NULL    
         2     A    2021-04-01  2021-09-06
```

which is correct for the data given above. This solution **also** works in situations where the `row_number` is not in sync with the dates (see [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=1b895c2c0cfc70250a00c1510d370e11))!

Comment: Wow, this is amazing! Works perfectly and I was able to follow and learn from the explanations so I super appreciate it. I feel like I've added a whole tool I didn't have before to my query toolbox. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic [gaps-and-islands](/questions/tagged/gaps-and-islands) situation.

### References

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014577/group-by-and-aggregate-sequential-numeric-values
- [Select longest continuous sequence](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35380/select-longest-continuous-sequence)

### Query

Like in the referenced questions, I'm going to use the Tabibitosan method to separate our groups, then just select the first one.

```
WITH start AS (
SELECT rn, 
    code, 
    from_date, 
    to_date, 
    lag(from_date) OVER (ORDER BY rn) AS next_from 
FROM t3 
WHERE code='A'
ORDER BY rn
),
group_identify AS (
SELECT *,
    CASE WHEN rn=1 OR next_from - to_date = 1
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    END AS group_cnt
FROM    start
), 
group_enumerate AS (
SELECT *,
    rn-sum(group_cnt) OVER (ORDER BY rn) AS grpn
FROM group_identify
)
SELECT rn, code, from_date, to_date
FROM group_enumerate
WHERE grpn=(select min(grpn) from group_enumerate)
ORDER BY rn
```

### Explanation

- The first table, `start`, pulls in the **From Date** from the previous line using `lag()`. Change `t3` to the name of your table and `code` to the code of interest here.
- The next table, `group_identify`, computes whether the current row is a candidate for a sequence, setting the field `group_cnt` to `1` if so, and `0` if not.
- The third table, `group_enumerate`, assigns a unique group number to each sequence by subtracting the count of groups from the row number `rn`. This is the [Tabibitosan method](https://www.toolbox.com/tech/data-management/blogs/tabibito-san-the-traveler-technique-in-sql-080216/).
- Finally, the outer query selects the lowest-numbered group and outputs the requested columns.

### Assumptions

- Rows are already numbered in the table. If this was not true then a window function like `row_number() OVER (ORDER BY from_date DESC) AS rn` could be used to generate it.
- Date ranges do not overlap.

### Caution

I did not do extensive testing to ensure all of the ordering works properly if the table is not organized as in the examples.