# Cumulative running SUM for date ranges with gaps

Tags: postgresql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I am looking for assistance to get a running sum of the difference between two dates that are on separate rows.

Table looks like:

| client_id | name | autopay_status | contract_id | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Contract 1 | Inactive | 1111 | "2019-08-30" | "2020-02-29" |
| 1 | Contract 1 | Inactive | 1112 | "2020-02-29" | "2020-08-29" |
| 1 | Contract 1 | Active | 1113 | "2020-08-29" | "2021-02-28" |
| 2 | Contract 2 | Inactive | 2221 | "2019-08-30" | "2020-02-29" |
| 2 | Contract 2 | Inactive | 2222 | "2020-02-29" | "2020-08-29" |
| 2 | Contract 2 | Active | 2223 | "2020-08-29" | "2021-02-28" |
| 3 | Contract 3 | Inactive | 3331 | "2019-08-30" | "2020-02-29" |
| 3 | Contract 3 | Inactive | 3332 | "2020-03-29" | "2020-09-29" |
| 3 | Contract 3 | Inactive | 3333 | "2020-09-29" | "2021-03-28" |
| 3 | Contract 3 | Active | 3334 | "2021-03-28" | "2021-09-28" |

I have a query that looks at the previous end_date and if it is within one day then that is a continuing contract.

```
SELECT
    case when
        (start_date - coalesce(lag(end_date) over (partition by client_id order by end_date), end_date)::date)::int <= 1 then true
         else false
    end as continous_contract,
    end_date - start_date as contract_days,
    client_id,
    contract_id,
    autopay_status,
    start_date,
    end_date
FROM
    client_contracts
ORDER BY
    client_id, start_date
```

This adds two extra alias columns.

| continuous_contract | contract_days | client_id | name | autopay_status | contract_id | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| true | 183 | 3 | Contract 3 | Inactive | 3331 | "2019-08-30" | "2020-02-29" |
| false | 184 | 3 | Contract 3 | Inactive | 3332 | "2020-03-29" | "2020-09-29" |
| true | 183 | 3 | Contract 3 | Inactive | 3333 | "2020-09-29" | "2021-03-28" |
| true | 182 | 3 | Contract 3 | Active | 3334 | "2021-03-28" | "2021-09-28" |

My goal here is to sum up the days a client has had a continuous contract
so table would look similar to below for the above example:

| sum_days | continuous_contract | contract_days | client_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 183 | true | 183 | 3 |
| 184 | false | 184 | 3 |
| 367 | true | 183 | 3 |
| 549 | true | 182 | 3 |
| 733 | true | 184 | 3 |
| 181 | false | 181 | 3 |

I have put together the below query, but it only sums up the previous two values.

```
SELECT
*
FROM
(
    SELECT
        *,
        case
            when cc.continuous_contract = true then
                cc.contract_days + coalesce(lag(cc.contract_days) over (partition by cc.client_id), 1)
            else cc.contract_days
        end as added_contract_days
    FROM (
        SELECT
            case when
                (start_date - coalesce(lag(end_date) over (partition by client_id order by end_date), end_date)::date)::int <= 1 then true
                 else false
            end as continuous_contract,
            end_date - start_date as contract_days,
            client_id,
            contract_id,
            autopay_status,
            start_date,
            end_date
        FROM
            client_contracts
        ) as cc
    ) as ccc
```

I am happy to change anything around to make this work.

Fiddle for assisting in seeing data and structure:
[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=7d5c77fe3fe30ea43c4126cf500777a2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can be done in three steps:

```
SELECT *, sum(contract_days) OVER (PARTITION BY client_id, contract_nr ORDER BY end_date) AS sum_days
FROM  (
   SELECT *, count(*) FILTER (WHERE NOT continous_contract) OVER (PARTITION BY client_id ORDER BY end_date) AS contract_nr
   FROM  (
      SELECT client_id, start_date, end_date
           , start_date <= lag(end_date, 1, end_date) OVER (PARTITION BY client_id ORDER BY end_date) + 1 AS continous_contract
           , end_date - start_date AS contract_days  -- + 1 ???
      FROM   client_contracts
      ) sub1
   ) sub2
ORDER  BY client_id, start_date;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_15&fiddle=5aa56189b93e0c1efbb7e476030f1e0f)*

The inner subquery `sub1` is basically what you started with, simplified.
[`lag()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html#FUNCTIONS-WINDOW-TABLE) optionally takes 3 arguments, the third being the fallback if no row is found.

`sub2` adds a `contract_nr` for each continuous group of rows: every gap in the contract interval starts a new contract.

The outer `SELECT` finally adds the running sum.

This assumes that contracts never overlap per client.

See:

- [Select longest continuous sequence](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35380/select-longest-continuous-sequence/35389#35389)

Aside: `end_date - start_date AS contract_days` looks like an off-by-one error? If lower and upper bound shall be included, add `+ 1`. (Of course, overlapping bounds are counted twice then.)