# Identify if the sequence of visits to an area id was interrupted at any point

Tags: postgresql, order-by, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have a PostgreSQL table `df` with the following information:

| area_id | trip_nr | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 3 | 29/06/2022 17:18:03 |
| a | 2 | 29/06/2022 17:18:02 |
| a | 1 | 29/06/2022 17:18:01 |
| b | 1 | 28/06/2022 19:21:03 |
| c | 3 | 28/06/2022 19:21:02 |
| e | 3 | 28/06/2022 19:21:01 |
| e | 2 | 27/06/2022 17:36:03 |
| c | 2 | 27/06/2022 17:36:02 |
| c | 1 | 27/06/2022 17:36:01 |
| e | 1 | 27/06/2022 16:55:03 |

I would like to add a column `continuous` that checks if the `trip_nr` to a particular `area_id` follows chronologically from the first visit based on the order of `timestamp`.

In other words, `continuous=True` if an `area_id` is visited for the nth time and the previous visits were to the same `area_id` all the way from n, n-1,...,1.

And, `continuous=False` if an `area_id` is visited for the n’th time, but a different `area_id` was visited somewhere in between the visits n, n-1,...,1 (i.e. the sequence of `trip_nr`’s is broken at some point).

An example of the desired output:

| area_id | trip_nr | timestamp | continous |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 3 | 29/06/2022 17:18:03 | True |
| a | 2 | 29/06/2022 17:18:02 | True |
| a | 1 | 29/06/2022 17:18:01 | True |
| b | 1 | 28/06/2022 19:21:03 | True |
| c | 3 | 28/06/2022 19:21:02 | False |
| e | 3 | 28/06/2022 19:21:01 | False |
| e | 2 | 27/06/2022 17:36:03 | False |
| c | 2 | 27/06/2022 17:36:02 | True |
| c | 1 | 27/06/2022 17:36:01 | True |
| e | 1 | 27/06/2022 16:55:03 | True |

How can I achieve this optimally? Clickhouse/SQL answers also welcome.

Note that the timestamp is not necessarily stored in order.

Comment: your solution doesn't make that much sense ``c  3  28/06/2022 19:21:02  False` should be in my opinion true or i don't get your logic

Comment: It should be False, because it is not continuous from 3, 2, 1. It visits 'e' in between.

Comment: sorry, i still don' get it can you explain after each true or flase why it has that calue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all involved columns `NOT NULL`, and no duplicate timestamps per `area_id`.

Undefined aspect: what if the same `area_id` is visited again (after a gap) and it starts over with `trip_nr = 1`. Still "continuous"?

##### Only the first trip per area is "continuous"

```
SELECT area_id, trip_nr, timestamp
     , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY area_id, grp ORDER BY timestamp) = trip_nr
       AND grp = min(grp) OVER (PARTITION BY area_id) AS continuous
FROM  (
   SELECT *
        , row_number() OVER (ORDER BY timestamp)
        - row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY area_id ORDER BY timestamp) AS grp
   FROM   df
   ) sub
ORDER  BY timestamp DESC;
```

##### Multiple "continuous" trips per area

```
SELECT area_id, trip_nr, timestamp
     , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY area_id, grp ORDER BY timestamp) = trip_nr AS continuous
FROM  (
   SELECT *
        , row_number() OVER (ORDER BY timestamp)
        - row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY area_id ORDER BY timestamp) AS grp
   FROM   df
   ) sub
ORDER  BY timestamp DESC;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GNipe5a8)

#### How?

Subtract the row number per partition of `area_id` from the total row number, then continuous rows produce the same group (`grp`) per `area_id`. Each gap starts a new group.

Then check whether the row number *within* each of those groups matches the `trip_nr`.
(And whether it's the first group per `area_id`?)

Related:

- [Select longest continuous sequence](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35380/select-longest-continuous-sequence/35389#35389)