# Grouping by sequential relationships with Postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

This is quite similar to [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17045/efficiently-select-beginning-and-end-of-multiple-contiguous-ranges-in-postgresql?lq=1) about continuous ranges, and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014577/group-by-and-aggregate-sequential-numeric-values) about grouping by sequential numbers, but differs in that the sequences are not numeric. Given the following relationships as key pairs

```
a -- b -- c      e -- f -- g
     |   /
     |  /
      d
```

This is the table with example data (also on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ef46b)):

```
CREATE TABLE relationships (
   name varchar(1),
   related varchar(1)
);

INSERT INTO relationships (name, related) VALUES 
('a', 'a'),
('a', 'b'),
('b', 'b'),
('b', 'a'),
('b', 'c'),
('b', 'd'),
('c', 'c'),
('c', 'b'),
('c', 'd'),
('d', 'd'),
('d', 'c'),
('d', 'b'),

('e', 'e'),
('e', 'f'),
('f', 'f'),
('f', 'e'),
('f', 'g'),
('g', 'g');
```

What is the most efficient way to produce an output that looks like this:

```
| group |    members    |
------------------------|
|   1   |  {a, b, c, d} |
|   2   |  {e, f, g}    |
```

or this:

```
| name |  group |
-----------------
|  a   |   1    |
|  b   |   1    |
|  c   |   1    |
|  d   |   1    |
|  e   |   2    |
|  f   |   2    |
|  g   |   2    |
```

I have thought about doing this operation outside of Postgres, but it seems like there must be a way to achieve this result with either a window function or PL/pgSQL.

Comment: Sorry, the "group" is what I'm trying to create. I have an SQLFiddle with an example schema - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ef46b

Comment: How do you find if a and b are related (member of the same group)?  Alternatively, why is there a split between d and e?

Comment: And how do you know what the starting node of the graph is?

Comment: @dezso - As mentioned above, it's in this schema - sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ef46b. Basically, 'name' is an entity, and 'related' is an entity that it relates to.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - you don't ;-). That's part of the problem.

Comment: In the schema, you can also think of each 'name' as a spatial entity, and 'related' as another entity that it touches.

Comment: If you can't determine the start of the graph even without SQL, there is no way this can be done with SQL.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name one can simply pick any node and find it's group, right?

Comment: @deszo: no I don't think so because there are self referencing nodes (=loops) in the data. There is e.g. a row with name=b and related=b

Comment: How do you ensure that all elements don't make up one group? Are you trying to mimic MapReduce algorithm?

Answer (score 2):

Ugly, but it works!

First, define `array_agg_mult` from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11763245/1956065)

```
CREATE AGGREGATE array_agg_mult (anyarray)  (
    SFUNC     = array_cat
   ,STYPE     = anyarray
   ,INITCOND  = '{}'
);
```

and then run the query

```
WITH summary AS (
  SELECT name, array_agg(related) AS touches
  FROM relationships
  GROUP BY name
), 

grouped AS (
  SELECT name, (
    SELECT array_agg(uniques) FROM (
      select distinct unnest(array_agg_mult(sub.touches)) AS uniques 
      ORDER BY uniques
    ) x
  ) my_group

  FROM summary LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT touches
    FROM summary r
    WHERE summary.touches && r.touches
    GROUP BY name, touches
  ) sub ON true
  GROUP BY summary.name
  ORDER BY summary.name
) 

SELECT DISTINCT my_group, row_number() over() as group_id 
FROM grouped 
GROUP BY my_group;
```

Which produces the following:

```
| my_group  |  group_id |
| {a,b,c,d} |      2    |
| {e,f,g}   |      1    |
```

SQLFiddle here - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c8a5b/20. I'm a novice with this kind of query, so please let me know if there is a more efficient way to do this!

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a classic problem in computer science: given a graph, determine all of the connected components.

This is what is called a "linear-time" problem.  In other words, it can be solved by examining each of the input data elements exactly once.  The simplest way to do this is by using either a depth-first or a breadth-first search:

- Set **id** to 1
- For each **x** in the set of nodes:

  - If **x** has not already been assigned a group id:

    - Do either a depth-first or breadth-first search (your choice) using the "relationships" table starting with **x** and assign group id **id** to all nodes found.
    - Increment **id**

If I understand the PostgreSQL code above, this is basically what you are already doing!  I think the combination of array_agg and LEFT JOIN LATERAL is essentially doing a breadth-first search.  If you are doing this operation only once, then this seems like a reasonable way to do it in PostgreSQL.

However, if you are going to be repeating this operation often, you will probably get a more efficient execution by creating a second table that stores group_id:

```
CREATE TABLE groups (
    name varchar(1) primary key,
    group_id integer
);
```

Then you can store this information as you determine it, and print it out very quickly with a simple query:

```
SELECT group_id, array_agg(name)::text FROM groups GROUP BY group_id
```

In fact, you can build this table iteratively as new relationships are added:

- For each new relationship (**a**, **b**):

  - SELECT distinct group_id FROM groups WHERE name in (**a**, **b**);
  - If the result set is empty:

    - Set **new** = SELECT max(group_id)+1 FROM groups
    - INSERT INTO groups VALUES (**a**, **new**);
    - If **a** <> **b**:

      - INSERT INTO groups VALUES (**b**, **new**);
  - Else if the first row of the result is **g**:

    - If **a** is not already in the table:

      - INSERT INTO groups VALUES (**a**, **g**);
    - If **a** <> **b** and **b** is not already in the table:

      - INSERT INTO groups VALUES (**b**, **g**);
    - If the result set has two rows and the second row is **h**:

      - UPDATE groups SET group_id = **g** WHERE group_id = **h**;
    - (* This last condition handles the case where a new relationship joins two existing groups *)

Is this more efficient?  That will depend greatly on the number of edges (relationships) in your data set and upon whether you are adding them all at once or a few at a time.